# Is there a way to have index.html functionality with content hosted on S3?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

Is there a way to make S3 default to an index.html page?  E.g.: My bucket object listing:

```
/index.html
/favicon.ico
/images/logo.gif
```

A call to **www.example.com/*index.html*** works great!  But if one were to call **www.example.com/** we'd either get a 403 or a REST object listing XML document depending on how bucket-level ACL was configured.

So, the question: Is there a way to have index.html functionality with content hosted on S3?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Amazon S3 now supports [Index Documents](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/IndexDocumentSupport.html)

The *index document* for a bucket can be set to something like `index.html`. When accessing the root of the site or a sub-directory containing a document of that name that document is returned.

It is extremely easy to do using the aws cli:

```
aws s3 website $MY_BUCKET_NAME --index-document index.html
```

You can set the *index document* from the AWS Management Console:

[image]

Comment: Yeah. I posted this as soon as I heard the announcement.

Comment: PS: Love the freehand circles ;)

Comment: unfortunately this works when it feels like it. I have this configures on one bucket that works great, and another bucket, won't work, still list the XML bullshit.

Comment: See the answer by fiatjaf to get the rest of the story. Just setting the Index Document is not enough. You have to be using a modified domain name as well.

Answer (score 80):

For people still struggling against this after 3 years, let me add some important information:

The URL for your website (and to which you have to point your DNS) is not

`<bucket_name>.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com`, but

`<bucket_name>.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com`.

If you use the first, it will not work as intended, no matter how much you config the [Index document](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/IndexDocumentSupport.html).

For a specific example, consider:

- http://www-example-com.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html works.
- http://www-example-com.s3.amazonaws.com/ fails with `AccessDenied`.
- http://www-example-com.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ works!

To get your true website address, go to your [S3 Management Console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/s3/home), select the target bucket, then `Properties`, then `Static Website Hosting`. It will show the website URL that will work.

Comment: Thank you for finally solving my problem!

Comment: Thank you! This has plagued me 15 times and I never understood why.

Comment: You deserve a medal Sir!

Comment: First thank you, clearly you managed to specify something AWS failed to. Now the second question: I encountered this while trying to host my static website using CloudFront (due to HTTPS). Now my index.html document works only inside the root folder but in all others I get the the NoSuchKey error. See https://sbarnea.com/contact/ -- if you add index.html it will work, it also works for the root but not for the folders.

Comment: It started to work for me too but it took many hours of waiting.

Comment: These are known as **Website Endpoints** - more good info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44297454/165673

Comment: awesome! It really helps

Answer (score 4):

You can easily solve it by Amazon CloudFront [link](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/). At Amazon CloudFront you could modify the root object. You can download manager here: m1.mycloudbuddy.com/downloads.html.

Comment: Ha, I had totally forgotten about this two-year old question.  Yes, CloudFront is much better at content deliver in general from S3.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. using AWS Cloudfront lets you assign a default file.

Answer (score 3):

Since It's been long time, this question being asked, and Amazon S3 changing their Interface. I would like to answer with updated screenshots.

We need to enable 'static web hosting' for S3 to serve as web hosting. 
- Go to Properties -> click on static web hosting -> Select 'use this bucket to host a website' 
- Enter the index document (index.html by default),  error document and redirection rules, if any. 
[image: Selecting static web hosting]

[image: use-this-bucket-to-host-a-website]

As answered in [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24377823/3086531), web hosting link would be: http://bucket-name.s3-website-region.amazonaws.com

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest reading [this thread](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/thread.jspa?threadID=10849&start=0&tstart=0) from 2006 (On Amazon web services developers connection). It seems there's no easy solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using dns webforwards and cloaking.  just forward to the complete path of the index.html

www.example.com forwards to http://www.example.com.s3.amazonaws.com and make sure you cloak the output.