# Difference between JWT and SAML?

Tags: saml, jwt

What are the main difference between JWT (Json Web Token) and SAML?

Can you suggest me any examples of these with spring security?

Comment: Have a look at this, more indepth, comparison and explanation: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/82587/json-web-tokens-vs-saml

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Both [SAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Assertion_Markup_Language) and [JWT](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-json-web-token-31) are security token formats that are not dependent on any programming language. SAML is the older format and is based on XML. It's used commonly in protocols like SAML-P, WS-Trust and WS-Federation (although not strictly required).

JWT (JSON Web Token) tokens are based on JSON and used in new authentication and authorization protocols like OpenID Connect and OAuth 2.0.

Comment: would you please suggest any spring sample implementation

Comment: I can't recommend anything from experience as I'm not a Java developer. But have a look at slide 50 of this deck: http://www.slideshare.net/JAX_London/spring-day-identity-management-with-spring-security-dave-syer

Comment: the SAML spec encompasses a protocol as well as a token format, JWT is token format only

Comment: I found this useful, even though it compares SAML2 with JWT:
https://medium.com/@robert.broeckelmann/saml2-vs-jwt-a-comparison-254bafd98e6

Answer (score 24):

Both are are used for authentication and authorization, commonly used for Single Sign-On (SSO) solutions.

**S**ecurity **A**ssertion **M**arkup **L**anguage *(SAML,pronounced SAM-el)*  is an XML-based standard for exchanging authentication and authorization data between parties, i.e. **IdP** (**Id**entity **P**rovider) and a **SP** (**S**ervice **P**rovider).

- An **IdP** (**Id**entity **P**rovider) : authenticates users and provides to Service Providers an Authentication Assertion if successful. Identity providers offer **User Authentication As A Service**.
- A **SP** (**S**ervice **P**rovider): relies on the Identity Provider to authenticate users.

| Term in SAML | Term in OAuth | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Client | Client | Example: A web browser |
| Identity Provider(IdP) | Authorization Server | Server that owns the user identities and credentials |
| Service Provider(SP) | Resource Server | The protected application |

---

**J**SON **W**eb **T**oken *(JWT, pronounced jot)* is a **ID Token** based on JSON to pass user information as Header, Payload and Signature structure. https://jwt.io/

OpenID Connect(**OIDC**) is built on the OAuth 2.0 protocol and uses an additional JSON Web Token (JWT), called an ID token. This token is a compact and self-contained (i.e. piece of data that is able to function independently) authentication mechanism that uses a JSON object to encode claims that are signed and encrypted. JWT can be used to authenticate clients, pass information between parties, or to authenticate APIs.

Use case:

- **OIDC** is specifically focused on user authentication and is widely used to enable user logins on consumer websites and mobile apps. for example Stackoverflow login with Google account.
- **SAML** commonly used to help enterprise users sign in to multiple applications using a single login.
- OIDC is a more modern, lightweight, and easier-to-use protocol compared to SAML, while SAML provides a more complete and complex solution for SSO and identity management in enterprise scenarios.

Comment: Concerning "*pronounced jot*", see https://www.rfc-editor.org/errata/eid5648

Answer (score 11):

In addition to SAML using XML and JWT using JSON, SAML is a protocol and a token format while JWT is only a token format.