# keycloak for better authorization in spring cloud

Tags: java, spring, keycloak

What is SAML of Keycloak, why do you need it, is it important, when should it replace with JWT, can I integrate with purpose authorization and authenticaion

Answer (score 0):

SAML is one of the supported protocol by Keycloak to secure your applications.

 Applications here could be a spring boot app which serves some business logic.
There is question which you could look into to understand the
[Difference between JWT and SAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27314076/difference-between-jwt-and-saml)