# Web extension SAML Authentication

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I'm trying to recieve JSON answer from a WebPage inside my Chrome Extension. Unfortunately, web page requires SAML authentication - so I can only access resource after I'm being logged in with user / password on different tab.

Is there any (easy) way to do SAML authentication from Extension? With basic authentication it would be quite easy, but I couldn't find any guide on how to do it with SAML.

Best regards

Frank

Comment: Based on this [documentation](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/advanced-integration-for-saml-sso-on-chrome-devices), SAML is applicable in G suites account. You might want to try using [User Authentication](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity), web authentication protocols that utilize HTTP features, but Chrome Apps run inside the app container; they don’t load over HTTP and can’t perform redirects or set cookies.

Comment: Use the [Chrome Identity API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity) to authenticate users: the getAuthToken for users logged into their Google Account and the launchWebAuthFlow for users logged into a non-Google account. This [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837553/saml-vs-federated-login-with-oauth) might help you differentiate a SAML and OAuth Authentication. Hope this helps.