# Which authentication/authorization solution to use for a java web project?

Tags: spring-security, java-ee-6, java-ee-5

What options do I have to enforce authentication/authorization in a java web app ?
From my research, there's:

- JAAS
- JNDI
- Spring security

Any others ? Does JEE5 or JEE6 have anything new ?

Comment: Which granularity do you want for authorization? Restrict access to some URL / method invocation for given user / role is enough for you? Or you want restrict access to domain objects  (access control lists)?

Comment: I want to be able to group users into groups; then prevent/allow groups to access URLs.

Comment: Do you use already Spring Framework in this application?

Answer (score 0):

See [Securing Web Applications](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncas.html) chapiter for JEE6. Also you can consider [Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/) as alternative for Spring Security. If you already use Spring Framework then just go with Spring Security.

Answer (score 0):

if you do not want to implement the identity-provider by yourself, you can consider using [OpenID](http://openid.net/). This way, you can use any OpenID provider to provide the authentication/authorization.

In addition, you can consider [OAuth2](http://oauth.net/).

Do not mix between the two, there are [many posts here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3376141/openid-vs-oauth/3376190#3376190) that can explain the differences...