# Verfiy user is who they say they are on an external website

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, authentication

I am developing a website for our GTA Online Crew, basically a gaming community, my issue lies in verifying that they are the user they say they are when they register (For example if there username on social club is GTOFAN01, we want to ensure that person uses the same username on our site when they register).

As we want all website users to have the same names from social club (owned by Rockstar and I have no way to change anything on there end...) to our website to avoid confusion / posers / trolls etc.

I've had a few ideas but they all create a lot of manual work or I am not sure how to implement, but I have narrowed it down...

1. Let anyone register and then manually send them a confirmation code through social club to the account name they have said they are.
2. somehow find out who they are currently logged in as on social club, if this matches the name they supplied then let them in.
3. find someway to send a message to there social club message box

2 is by far the best, but I can figure out a way to achieve it... I cannot read cookies or session variables from another domain.

Any ideas?

Comment: what is this "they are the user they say they are when they register." ?

Comment: For example there username on social club may be GTOFAN01, we want to ensure that person uses the same username on our site when then register.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I ended up going was generating a random qoute for the user to post on the social club (checking it didn't exist first), as the social club feed is public I can then check to see if the qoute was posted and by whom, if this matches who they told us they were then there registration is accepted.

Obviously this is not the greatest solution, but it works and as I've stated I have no control over the social club nor do they offer any way to authenticate a user.

The other befit to this method is it encourages use of the feed which we also wanted to do.

Answer (score 1):

There are several different ways of achieving ["federated identity"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federated_identity).  I would recommend taking a look at [OAuth](http://oauth.net/) and [OpenId](http://openid.net/).  [Asp.net Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity) has OAuth integration.

See also:

- [OpenID vs. OAuth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3376141/openid-vs-oauth)
- [What's the difference between OpenID and OAuth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087031/whats-the-difference-between-openid-and-oauth)

Comment: Yes. Both OpenId and OAuth are pretty common - but you would have to find out if the "Social Club" site has support.