# Google Federated Login (OpenID + OAuth 2)

Tags: oauth, openid, google-api, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to get OpenID working with OAuth 2 for using Google's API. I only want the user to have to "grant access" once when they login for the first time. Here is the flow I have so far:

1. User clicks "Login with Google"
2. My server signs in the User with OpenID. With federated login I receive an OAuth Request Token.

From https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID#oauth it says the next step is to exchange the request token for an access token. However, I see a couple problems with this:

1. It is an OAuth 1 API call.
2. It requires a verifier. Don't I need the user to "grant access" to receive the verifier? How is this federated?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use OAuth 2.0 based authentication:
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login

This is also referred to as OpenID Connect.

This will redirect to your site with an authorization code.  You then exchange that for an access token.  You can [validate](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login#validatingtoken) the access token by calling the TokenInfo endpoint with a simple REST request.  This will give you a simple userid identifier.

After, you make a call to get the detailed [profile information](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login#userinfocall), such as name + email, etc.

You can see more about how it works with this great demo:
http://oauthssodemo.appspot.com/

Comment: Is OAuth 2.0 really same as OpenID Connect. Is OAuth 2.0 a protocol to implement the Authentication part of OpenID Connect?

Comment: I also found this on stackoverflow. Please check its answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087031/whats-the-difference-between-openid-and-oauth