# Passport/Twitter authorization

Tags: twitter-oauth, passport.js

Learning Node, Express, and Passport.  I want to be able to give my users the ability to sign in via Twitter, Gmail, Facebook, and maybe one or two other services.  I finally made some headway with Passport but when I click the link to log in, Twitter's page says the following...

> This application will be able to:
>
> - Read Tweets from your timeline.
> - See who you follow

I'm not really interested in being able to do either of those things, and I'm worried that privacy concerns will deter my users from using this method.  I've looked at a ton of examples online but thus far I haven't seen anything that lets me control this.

The only thing I'm interested in is authentication and getting minimal user information like First Name, Last Name, and maybe an E-mail address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I've made the same mistake many others have made... confusing OAuth and OpenID.  I think I only need OpenId for my purposes.  I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087031/whats-the-difference-between-openid-and-oauth) SO question helpful as I was researching everything.