# Scope to get email address alone?

Tags: scope, oauth-2.0, google-plus, google-oauth, google-authentication

I use the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email` scope to get an email address of the authenticated user. But while authenticating, Google prompts the user:

> The app would like to:
>
> - Know who you are on Google+ (for which the help icon says: *This app is requesting permission to associate you with your public Google profile*)
> - View your email address

I don't want the user's Google+ related information. I am using the [OAuth2 authentication method](https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth). For Authsub request authentication it requires only email address access. How can I get access to the user's email address alone?

[image]
[image]

Comment: What you need might be OpenID

[Difference between OpenID and OAuth][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087031/whats-the-difference-between-openid-and-oauth

Comment: Did you ever fix this? (Related: [Why do you need to know who I know on Google?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234365/why-do-you-need-to-know-who-i-know-on-google) on Meta Stack Exchange.)

Comment: Unfortunately, @zinking, Google [is deprecating OpenID in April 2015](https://developers.google.com/+/api/auth-migration#timetable).

Comment: Though the above question is much older, it seems more answers are available at [Is there a way to *only* get a user's email address with Google's OAuth2 implementation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24410179/is-there-a-way-to-only-get-a-users-email-address-with-googles-oauth2-impleme).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [Google+ Sign-In](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/), the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login` scope is automatically included, which would be why you were seeing that portion of the permission dialog.

If you do not need the enhanced features that come along with the Google+ Sign-In feature, then you'd probably want to do a standard OAuth flow. See the [Google OAuth scenarios](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#scenarios) for a solution that might fit your needs where you can ask for only the email scope.

Comment: I didn't use Google+ Sign-In. I just used to call this link for authentication https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email&state=%2Fprofile&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Foauth2-login-demo.appspot.com%2Fcode&response_type=code&client_id=812741506391.apps.googleusercontent.com&approval_prompt=force

Comment: I'm seeing this as well. Regardless of whether one uses Google+ Sign-In or any G+ services, adding the userinfo.email scope now shows "Know who you are on Google+" on the permission request page.

As a service provider, I don't need to know who the user is. As a user, I don't want Google encouraging services to obtain - or simply granting them - more access than is actually needed.

Comment: +1. In my case the only scope I am requesting is "email", yet the user is being prompted for "View your email address" and "Know who you are on Google+". Feedback from potential users is they do NOT want to give access to what they perceive to be personal information.

Comment: I had an old screenshot and in the last month, it changed from "Know who you are on Google" (closer to accurate, though not as specific as it should be) to "Know who you are on Google+." It should simply say "Know your email address" and grant exactly that.

Comment: This is another reason why WhatsApp became successful. They don't want to know anything about their users and there is no registration. Google hasn't learnt from that and still continues to raise questions by users when presented with the permissions screen when all you want to do is authenticate the user and get their ID and nothing more. Asking "Know who you are on Google" is a good way to lose a lot of new users.

Comment: Yes, exactly. The way SO site follow this as well. never ask more than you needed when authenticate

Comment: @zinking the SE dev team is having a problem because of this right now, with OpenID being deprecated.

Comment: @AndroidDev: I have a similar issue as the OP, but all I want is JUST the user ID, and a way to authenticate users on my server. As far as I can see, the only way to do that is to ask them for their Google+ information and a sheeetload of other things. Do you know if this has changed (no request would be ideal) and I'm just not finding it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still searching for this, I think this might help. In the gapi.auth2.init method in the Google Sign In JS client reference, set fetch_basic_profile to false (it's true by default). Now using the scope param for the same method specify "email", "profile" permissions