# Is there a way to *only* get a user's email address with Google's OAuth2 implementation?

Tags: google-oauth, oauth2-playground

I have a "Sign in with Google+" button on my page.  When people click on it, I want the *only* thing they authorize to be "View your email address."

I *don't* want "Know who you are on Google" or "View basic information about your account."  I *only* want their email address.

I'm playing on the OAuth 2.0 Playground (https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) and see this:

---

Scope: `email`

Requests:

1. Know who you are on Google
2. View your email address

---

Scope: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email`  (and this one is deprecated)

Requests:

1. Know who you are on Google
2. View your email address

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Indeed, I've noticed that too. And I found [an explanation from February 2013 here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/oauth2-dev/p8am51gyrns):

> This is an intentional change to more precisely communicate to users the set of permissions that is being granted. Through knowledge of the user's email address it is possible, via indirect means, to locate the user's profile address. In the interest of more accurate disclosure, thus, we are prompting users to approve such disclosure.

Comment: That's not what I wanted to hear, but thank you for pointing this out.  I wish this was explicit in the docs.

Comment: Stack Exchange might have been trying to convince Google otherwise: [*We have several guys at Google I/O this week that are going to try and pin the Google guys down and see if we can get some reasonable change here.*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234365/why-do-you-need-to-know-who-i-know-on-google/234369?noredirect=1#comment771284_234515) Of course, this is an old change, but since Google is deprecating OpenID, this is getting noticed.

Answer (score 4):

Not exactly what you want, but combining `profile` and `email` will at least give one a less scary description for the first:

> This app would like to:
>
> - View basic information about your account
> - View your email address

...with the help for the first saying:

> More info
>
> View your name, public profile URL, and photo
> View your gender
> View your country, language, and timezone

To me, this feels better than the vague *This app is requesting permission to associate you with your public Google profile* which one gets as [the More Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDRMZ.png) for *Know who you are on Google+*, when not explicitly using scope `profile`, or when using scope `openid`.

[image]
[image]

As an aside: LinkedIn's OAuth 2 also always needs a user [to grant access to *Your Profile Overview*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Njgi2.png), even if an application only needs some unique identifier. Other than with Google's explanation [in Owen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24410179/is-there-a-way-to-only-get-a-users-email-address-with-googles-oauth2-impleme/24424716#24424716), I assume LinkedIn really wants developers to use their network features.