# Redirect user to gmail after login

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid, google-apps

I have employees on google apps id like to authenticate (with their google apps username and password) at login.mydomain.com > authenticate without being redirected to the google login page > send them to gmail.

Would I do this via Oauth 2.0 or OpenID? A simpler method perhaps?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087031/whats-the-difference-between-openid-and-oauth

Comment: I appreciate the link as the information provided there is helpful but I still don't understand or see a solution. Is there some simple code for this im missing in your link?

Comment: you got the difference, rest you should try to work out. In doing so if you find any problem relating to programming, then post it reflecting your efforts as well

Comment: What do you want me to say rookieB? I'm a complete idiot? I get it im pretty worthless as a person and programmer in general; I should be shot for both. I've been looking for TWO weeks and im at my end for a lot. I've seen many pages and docs that I don't get and it's my own dumb fault. Now I'm here at stackoverflow failed and miserable asking for help. I don't even know where to begin, what is the right choice of docs/api's/services/platforms etc. - I couldn't even post a failed program if I'd like.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can use oAuth.

you could use Google Accounts as your identity provider, and configure your resource-server (your application, I guess) to redirect your users to Google account, and give their creds there.

The flow: your users will try to access your resource-server (your app?), then, since it is protected by oAuth, they will be redirected to Google Accounts for authentication and authorization. after authentication, oAuth mechanism will redirect your users back to the original URL (your app)

HTH