# "OpenID2 for Google accounts is going away on April 20, 2015". Do I need to worry?

Tags: asp.net, oauth

I am developing a website by using ASP.NET and I use Oauth feature to register users to my website. I downloaded DontNetOpenOauth from nuget packages for the Visual studio 2013.
Up to now I implemented facebook authentication. I hope to use google authentication as well. But when I go to there website it says that.

**"OpenID2 for Google accounts is going away on April 20, 2015."**

When I go to detail page of this warning it says

*"Some applications and websites use OpenID 2.0 for authentication when you're signing in, and to access data that you've given them permission to access. Starting April 20, 2015, OpenID 2.0 will no longer work for Google Accounts.
If you've seen a warning that's brought you to this page, it means that you're using an application or website with OpenID 2.0 and may be affected by this change. For more information, we recommend you visit that application's help center, or contact its support team."*

Here is the link.

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6135882

Honest with you guys I am not familiar with this oauth authentication process. 
What is this warning message? Do I need to worry about this? Is there any changes should I need to do or any packages should I need to install?

Comment: [It seems you're confusing OAuth with OpenID.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087031/whats-the-difference-between-openid-and-oauth)

Comment: Here's [a conversation](http://community.sitepoint.com/t/the-death-of-openid-2-0/110947) related to this topic.

Answer (score -1):

No you don't need to worry, it just means that developers @ Stackoverflow will have to change their code a little bit but it should work fine.

EDIT:

You have to change your code from OpenID to OAuth 2 use http://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer with a minimal scope developers.google.com/+/api/oauth#login-scopes which is `profile` and from that profile you can determine which user is that and log them in

You don't have to save the token returned because you won't be needing it again until the next login which you will be automatically handed the new or same token by Goole

My Advice is to use the ID can be found using this [document](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get#response)

```
{
 "kind": "plus#person",
 "etag": "\"RqKWnRU4WW46-6W3rWhLR9iFZQM/hGBwxYeYt07li9hNmxa2J7GE_0c\"",
 "nickname": "GreYFoX",
 "occupation": "Computer Engineer",
 "skills": "iOS Developement, Android Developement",
 "birthday": "0000-09-20",
 "gender": "male",
 "emails": [
  {
   "value": "@#^$%@^#@gmail.com",
   "type": "account"
  }
 ],
 "urls": [
  {
   "value": "http://www.myspace.com/Shereef",
   "type": "otherProfile",
   "label": "Shereef"
  },
  {
   "value": "http://Shereefz.spaces.live.com",
   "type": "otherProfile",
   "label": "shereefz"
  },
  {
   "value": "http://www.plaxo.com/profile/showPublic/Shereef",
   "type": "otherProfile",
   "label": "shereef"
  },
  {
   "value": "http://cid-c74ed9e76d675051.profile.live.com",
   "type": "otherProfile",
   "label": "@&#$%&@#%^$@live.com"
  },
  {
   "value": "http://www.plaxo.com/profile/showPublic/null",
   "type": "otherProfile",
   "label": "null"
  },
  {
   "value": "http://pulse.yahoo.com/_VMZ2QYN3AWG57HS5IUW4T2KHRM",
   "type": "otherProfile",
   "label": "Shereef Marzouk"
  },
  {
   "value": "http://about.me/Shereef",
   "type": "otherProfile",
   "label": "About.me"
  },
  {
   "value": "http://www.youtube.com/user/Shereefz",
   "type": "otherProfile",
   "label": "Shereef Marzouk"
  },
  {
   "value": "http://www.youtube.com/user/Shereefz",
   "type": "otherProfile",
   "label": "Shereef Marzouk"
  },
  {
   "value": "http://www.myspace.com/Shereef",
   "type": "otherProfile",
   "label": "Shereef"
  },
  {
   "value": "http://Shereefz.spaces.live.com",
   "type": "otherProfile",
   "label": "shereefz"
  },
  {
   "value": "http://profiles.google.com/17F648F7-5C7D-42D4-A40F-CAC12280C712",
   "type": "otherProfile",
   "label": "SheefoPad"
  },
  {
   "value": "http://www.youtube.com/user/Shereefz",
   "type": "otherProfile",
   "label": "Shereef Marzouk"
  },
  {
   "value": "http://Shereefz.spaces.live.com",
   "type": "otherProfile",
   "label": "shereefz"
  },
  {
   "value": "http://www.myspace.com/Shereef",
   "type": "otherProfile",
   "label": "Shereef"
  },
  {
   "value": "http://profiles.google.com/17F648F7-5C7D-42D4-A40F-CAC12280C712",
   "type": "otherProfile",
   "label": "SheefoPad"
  },
  {
   "value": "https://profiles.google.com/104183538590490028018/buzz",
   "type": "contributor",
   "label": "Buzz"
  },
  {
   "value": "https://developers.google.com/groups/chapter/103706763079402130148/",
   "type": "contributor",
   "label": "GDG Alexandria (Google Developers Group Alexandria)"
  },
  {
   "value": "http://www.shereef.net",
   "type": "contributor",
   "label": "Shereef"
  },
  {
   "value": "http://shereef.net/resume",
   "type": "other",
   "label": "Resume"
  },
  {
   "value": "http://shereef.net/blog",
   "type": "other",
   "label": "Blogger"
  },
  {
   "value": "http://about.me/shereef",
   "type": "other",
   "label": "About.me"
  },
  {
   "value": "http://pulse.yahoo.com/sheefoz",
   "type": "other",
   "label": "sheefoz"
  },
  {
   "value": "http://facebook.com/Shereefz",
   "type": "other",
   "label": "shereefz"
  },
  {
   "value": "http://www.linkedin.com/in/shereef",
   "type": "other",
   "label": "shereef"
  }
 ],
 "objectType": "person",
 "id": "104183538590490028018",
 "displayName": "Shereef Marzouk",
 "name": {
  "familyName": "Marzouk",
  "givenName": "Shereef"
 },
 "tagline": "Senior Mobile Developer / Team lead at X Digital Group",
 "braggingRights": "XDG Hero",
 "aboutMe": "<span>Shereef Marzouk is an Egyptian mobile applications developer who enjoys his work very much, with many years of experience of development in mobile and general development, Shereef also loves helping people and love sharing, He also develops free-lance applications under his personal company name Tools Era (ToolsEra), Shereef is an Egyptian with his own cultural views and politic, Shereef is not your typical Egyptian nor Developer.</span>",
 "relationshipStatus": "engaged",
 "url": "https://plus.google.com/+ShereefMarzouk",
 "image": {
  "url": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-P9UMptk6e5U/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAFzp0/v3ArGL-l8Tg/photo.jpg?sz=50",
  "isDefault": false
 },
 "organizations": [
  {
   "name": "Alexandria Higher Institute of Engineering and Technology",
   "title": "Computer Engineering",
   "type": "school",
   "startDate": "2005",
   "endDate": "2011",
   "primary": false
  },
  {
   "name": "English Lycee Liberity",
   "title": "School",
   "type": "school",
   "startDate": "1994",
   "endDate": "2004",
   "primary": false
  },
  {
   "name": "Sidi Gaber Language School",
   "title": "K.G.",
   "type": "school",
   "startDate": "1992",
   "endDate": "1994",
   "primary": false
  },
  {
   "name": "X Digital Group",
   "title": "Senior Mobile Developer / Team Lead",
   "type": "work",
   "startDate": "2012",
   "primary": true
  },
  {
   "name": "X Digital Group",
   "title": "Interactive Touch Screen and Mobile Core Developer",
   "type": "work",
   "startDate": "2012",
   "endDate": "2013",
   "primary": false
  },
  {
   "name": "Health-Insights",
   "title": "Android / iOS / C#.NET Developer",
   "type": "work",
   "startDate": "2011",
   "endDate": "2012",
   "primary": false
  }
 ],
 "placesLived": [
  {
   "value": "Alexandria, Egypt",
   "primary": true
  },
  {
   "value": "KSA"
  },
  {
   "value": "Lybia"
  },
  {
   "value": "Egypt"
  },
  {
   "value": "Qatar"
  }
 ],
 "isPlusUser": true,
 "language": "en",
 "ageRange": {
  "min": 21
 },
 "circledByCount": 707,
 "verified": false,
 "cover": {
  "layout": "banner",
  "coverPhoto": {
   "url": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-kp8ALVVOa1o/U-Bo2sjE9GI/AAAAAAAFkaA/PWKY2q2e9lY/s630-fcrop64=1,0000208effb2f94e/_MG_0344-SMILE.jpg",
   "height": 626,
   "width": 940
  },
  "coverInfo": {
   "topImageOffset": -294,
   "leftImageOffset": 0
  }
 }
}
```

search for `"id": "104183538590490028018"` in the json i pasted here

P.S. Open all links in this answer because they will benefit you.

Also remember when requesting profile to use the id as me because you won't have the logging in user profile

Comment: I dont get it Shereef Marzouk. What is the connection between my website and stackoverflow? :)

Comment: I thought you were getting this on SOF, because i found your article because SOF got it too for open ID, sorry then, you have to change your code and use OAuth https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer  with a minimal scope https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth#login-scopes which is profile and from that profile you can determine which user is that and log them in

Comment: Sorry for the confusion