# Node.js Provider auth (oauth, OpenId) with SPA or mobile app

Tags: authentication, oauth, ionic-framework, sails.js, openid

I have :

- a *backend* app, done with *[sails.js](http://sailsjs.org/)*.
- a mobile application, done with *[ionic framework](http://ionicframework.com/)*.

I would like to accomplish :

- give to the users, on my login page, the opportunity to sign-up/sign-in with facebook, twitter, google, and "local".
- on my server, I'd like to have a single collection of users, registred, with both local users and provider-authenticated users.

---

My primary goal, through this question, is to **understand** the multiple strategies and concerns of provider-authentication inside SPA (be a web app or a native mobile app). I've read many things about [0Auth, OpenID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087031/whats-the-difference-between-openid-and-oauth), c[lient-side auth vs server-side auth](https://github.com/oauth-io/oauthd/wiki/Understanding-client-side-flow-and-server-side-flow), session based auth vs token based auth... I just don't get it. There is too much information out there about this and I'm pretty lost.

- What are the possible flows ?
- I think I got that I can authenticate with both OpenID and 0Auth, but which one *should* I use ?
- On mobile, can I authenticate with "the facebook app" instead of using a web endpoint ?
- I usually hear about "callbacks" after auth, what about them in a mobile app, where there is no web-server ?

NB: I'm not directly looking for implementations or libraries (like [passport](http://passportjs.org/) or [sails-auth](https://github.com/tjwebb/sails-auth)). I'm looking for an explainations of the different approaches and flows. Though, I'm open to discover some libraries as *examples* of the words