# What is the correct way to use access_token?

Tags: oauth, asp.net-core-webapi, windows-live

I'm trying to use OAuth. In this example the provider was Windows Live. The redirect returned this fragment. I have added line breaks before the ampersands to make it a bit easier to read.

```
access_token=EwAwA61DBAAUGCCXc8wU/zFu9QnLdZXy%2bYnElFkAAQcQQB3c7oVYQmQhyeTOiw1Tp5iA7cjrLJbEnvXVoDlu48mjv7WX35RRIK3L3miAQEUrn5ZVNRSUV8dqiZi4kIko93k2bODqpIY7r/nBRmnTTbInajZm0iF1FLjXaFJGzM/XJN4jZiZUtipwaNu66cSwbEhNVUWwZufHjE7SNDUQze3/ciGP9c%2bTampSUS23u%2bcuKrCbj8jPhFIj2Tbritf83YcVaXLJHpEYVz2a1GKHm8/TPot2MgcjD3yBOBd5b/QBImASEcdOpouiYIshi1Ddy20iYL1Jv6JRpPExeWd8q9sEfk4a%2btMHIPFJ%2bdy0e6X9nRMjlx%2bHP0FhUrOp4rADZgAACD41pKeivbukAAIVEy964MrcJsT6MwfHHf54bi9Nfhek/vARUG32qt1HId/3GgYDKcXblAk6I7qW%2boywDMa%2bck59pJms7/pEGqSkLtY%2b5M86%2bWvSG9bNAJWfQnKT1re5L4AxpbJ2J7JOw9md%2byBnt9I3hk%2bQGoY4ZoSMTtZ2QOxIH0rfgxVqrebUjAcCf1AIl7yBusgF1zJITPTBX1fLaEw48VjXjNygQq/N82%2baKZhU2ZMBTtUzgnod4SMrb/IOaQsDF6prVTihGHae6rbRL/Ul4C/au59NAijEBB9evjM6PxSMMpMmag6VTXdVeLeCBFitFwcjtRUH38yIuhPGalBnRTVHyLpm8cS06mrQM2n5j9XnMFBtQzEQEtdvtOsUkIgpVYmqZE38CEh9YAjJBxG1Xo9Pdz/DnHflfc3PWtO1xMZsP/krBMQFxQRTPBOiNv%2bH2DPF1TED35iW%2bS5VDbxjSur1dCVAPqv3Vbduia1moJ1AUYPm9P7%2bcY%2bIV3skuz4Dzk0zQPgU3h7N6zPwr0oi%2bNe548sk6Cqq/wbF7oV6ytuAc0fbedf49I7QA8x8BEruePwNWj2N6v2vJQqQm6fOC%2by7ZQSsJ9830hD6E5yp4YVht%2bux%2b8wu%2bDQ9x/VB6BXLNC%2b4Q2aIhDQmui/JMrgHXgo2okv9FywwVQdaSLXVasfrCVmqzDwGFhIC
&token_type=bearer
&expires_in=3600
&scope=wl.signin%20wl.emails
&user_id=AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB1EauoOQMnYy_bu42gkx90
&state=STATE
```

and I parsed that into name value pairs applying decodeURIcomponent to each.

That gave me an access_token value of

```
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
```

As I understood it, at this point all I have to do is add a header `Authorization: Bearer`*token value* but doing so for a route protected by `[Authorization] produces 401 Unauth with a type of Basic. This leaves me at a bit of a loss as to how to proceed.

Looking at the browser debug info I see

```
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error=invalid_token
```

- Does the token being invalid mean this is an inappropriate token or that it can't be parsed as a token?
- Is my methodology so far correct?
- Is there some kind of server configuration I need to make?
- Suggested next steps?

The Access token looks a bit like Base64 but it's not valid base64, I checked. Just thinking about the nature of a token, it's probably just the claims encrypted with the token issuer's private key. If that were so you could check the integrity of a token by decrypting the token using the issuer's public key, but I can't see how to use this observation to figure out why I have a 401.

### Update

This is the startup.cs code that introduces token checking

```
  app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
  {
    SaveToken = true,
    TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters
  });
```

and [this auth0 web page](https://jwt.io/) cannot decode my token *as a JWT token*. Further reading suggests that a JWT token has three dot-separated sections each base64 encoded, and this is simply not present in the tokens I'm receiving from both Windows Live and Google (I've tested with both now).

So perhaps I need to restructure the token request if I want JWT tokens. More on this next episode. Feel free to write the next episode as an answer, if you know what I ought to be doing, endpoint and parameters etc. This other question [What is the difference between id_token and access_token in Auth0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31495063/what-is-the-difference-between-id-token-and-access-token-in-auth0?rq=1) appears to be salient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An access_token is what is says on the box - a token for *access* to a particular resource.

A JWT is an identity token. To get one of those, what I need to do is

- use this endpoint: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
- specify a response_type of `id_token`
- Include a nonce
- Specify a scope of `openid`.

But returning to the question of how to use an access token, you use it as a bearer token in the authorization header in a requestion to the provider's endpoint for the scope in question, eg wl.email