# How does the Bearer token works in SCIM

Tags: oauth-2.0, authorization, okta, bearer-token, scim

I'm creating a set of API endpoints that should be compliant with [SCIM](http://www.simplecloud.info/) schemas to work as a SCIM server for [Okta platform](https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/scim/scim-20/).

The SCIM schema is clear to me, but I'm having problems understanding the Authorization. According to the SCIM docs, the authorization type should be "Authorization Bearer Token."

Here was my first problem: For me, the authorization token should be the same [JWT](https://jwt.io/) that I use for OAuth 2.0 authorization, but now, [thanks to SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34930402/3943162),  I know that is not true. The JWT and the use of Password Grant Flow is just a convention and not a rule.

Also, when I tried to create an example [SCIM app](https://www.okta.com/integrations/scim-2-0-test-app-oauth-bearer-token/) into Okta platform, the only option available was a static token and not the pair client_id/client_token that I was expecting to use OAuth 2 (*Side note:* This is possible when using a SAML application and use SCIM for provisioning, but not with SCIM only app).

The problem is: What now? SCIM should be used with some specific type of token? Does it force some [Oauth grant type](https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/authorization-code/)? Which one?

I know that I'm probably making some mess with all these concepts, but is there any simple explanation for the use of tokens with SCIM?

OBS: I'm using Okta for now, but it should comply with any SCIM client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most customers who use SCIM w/ Okta, just used a static token for Authentication to SCIM Servers. So, they are not using an token generated via an Oauth grant.

I know the engineers at Okta have done some research, so that Okta Oauth Tokens can be used for a SCIM connection with Okta, but most Cloud/(SAS) services do not support this today, so I would expect it might be a while before we see Okta (and most Cloud IDPs) using Oauth Tokens for SCIM connections.

You are on the right track, in fact your ahead of the curve. You'll likely have to use a static generated token for SCIM today.

Comment: Do you have any good documentation or tutorial to implement it? The official Okta documentation is a little bit vague and confusing.

Answer (score 2):

The SCIM 2.0 Test App that you create in your Okta org for testing your SCIM server app is just a template app for testing your service. Hence, in the API Integration tab, you see a static OAuth Bearer Token.

After you have completed your testing successfully, you should be submitting this app to get it integrated to OIN by filling out this [form](https://oinmanager.okta.com/).Please refer to this [guide](https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/submit-app/openidconnect/overview/).

In the submission form below

[image]

you should be filling the OAuth endpoint details. Once the app is integrated in OIN, Okta actually does an OAuth request to the scim server and it is [Authorization Code grant flow](https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/build-provisioning-integration/prepare-api/#authentication).

Comment: I think you can remain with Header Authentication, then you have to provide token to OKTA with base URL, OKTA will send it in header of every request and it's our responsibility to  maintain and change it.