# Is it possible to use OAuth to authenticate user and generate token?

Tags: authentication, oauth

I'm curious about OAuth behavior. Suppose there is a simple web site which is user able to login with there own credentials. Currently session stores required details about authenticated user after user successfully log in to sysytem. Instead of session,is it possible to use OAuth in this kind of scenario ? Please explain. Thanks !!

Comment: `OAuth` is typically used for `Authorization` not `Authentication`, this SO post has a lot of good information as well as multiple links for reading about `OAuth`, (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33702826/oauth-authorization-vs-authentication)

Comment: Thanks @RyanWilson . Does it mean OAuth can not use for `Authentication` ?