# HTTP Authentication header for OpenID authorization codes

Tags: rest, http, authentication, http-headers, openid

Is there a standard HTTP Authentication scheme which is appropriate to use with OpenID Connect? The scenario I have in mind is as follows:

An HTTP Service requires authentication of users. One of the possible authentication methods is to use a federated identity from a 3rd party OpenID Provider. The Service is registered with the 3rd party OpenID Provider as a confidential client, and possesses a client_id and a client secret.

When a user tries to access the HTTP Service, the server responds with a `401 Unauthorized` and a `WWW-Authenticate` header containing information about how to initiate an authentication request with the OpenID Provider:

```
WWW-Authenticate: OpenIDConnect realm="MyService", client_id="1234-5678", authorization_url="https://provider/authorize"
```

The client contacts the authorization endpoint, authenticates, and then obtains an authorization code. The code is then specified in a subsequent request to the Service via the `Authorization` header, e.g.:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1

Authorization: OpenIDConnect client_id="1234-5678", code="AAABAAA..."
```

The Service will use the code to obtain an ID Token from the OpenID Provider and establish an authenticated session with the client, e.g. by setting a cookie or returning a new set of credentials to use for subsequent requests.

The `OpenIDConnect` scheme is something I made up for this example. I have tried searching for a standard way to do something similar, and the absence of results has left me with the following possible answers:

1. I have not searched hard enough.
2. What I am trying to do is misguided and wrong.
3. Everybody implements their own custom authentication schemes for this purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you did not know where to look for in the first place. Since [RFC 7353](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235), authentication schemes in HTTP are subject to the [IANA HTTP Authentication Scheme Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-authschemes/http-authschemes.xhtml). In said registry, you are going to find the `OAuth` scheme which is subject to [RFC 5849, section 3.5.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849#section-3.5.1) and is looking a lot like what you are looking for. That being said, however, this is for OAuth 1.0. OAUth 2.0 is resorting to the `Basic` ([RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750)) and `Bearer` ([RFC 6750](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750)) schemes.

This in its entirety is concernig *authorization* (via OAuth). OpenID's realm is *authentication*, though. You may want to look at [What's the difference between OpenID and OAuth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087031/whats-the-difference-between-openid-and-oauth)

Comment: Thanks. Since OpenID Connect is based on OAuth 2.0, I suppose that an OAuth 1.0 scheme would be inappropriate to use for my purpose. I think `Bearer` is inappropriate for two reasons: (1) it is for OAuth 2.0 access tokens, whereas what I need in the end is an id_token (as you pointed out, I am interested in authentication rather than authorization); and (2) I need to send an authorization code, not a token. I am effectively looking for a scheme that can be used to transfer an authorization code from a User Agent to a Confidential Client, as described in the OIDC Core spec.

Comment: But anyway, since the registry you linked to does not contain anything appropriate for my exact use case, I guess the answer is that no standard scheme has been defined.

Comment: @UlrikRasmussen Perhaps [this guide](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-basic-1_0.html) is of help to you? (Note [this part](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-basic-1_0.html#TokenRequest)) But you are right: There is no auth scheme specifically reserved for OpenID Connect.