# Egerrit Authorization on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gerrit, mylyn

I have my Gerrit server running that is accepting sign-in via GitHub.

- Try 1: Now I have Eclipse Oxygen(3.7) and now while configuring it asks for username and password which I don't have.
- Try 2: I also tried via mylyn gerrit config as in the following image - the same issue occurs

[image]

Here I can use anonymous login, but don't want that.

Can I have EGerrit Gerrit Configuration without username and password??

[Eclipse Mylyn Gerrit config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5Io8.png)

Comment: To _Try2_: Are you sure, anonymous login is not only used to validate Gerrit server settings?

Comment: No, it is exactly like what we have in Gerrit anonymous login. You can just see the changset same as Gerrit UI but you can't edit or make changes.

Comment: I see, EGerrit supports [OpenID for authentication but not yet OAuth for authorisation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1087071/6505250): see [Eclipse bug 479783](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=479783)

Comment: That's correct howlger, so i am stuck.   
Gerrit server has : GitHub sign in,
Eclipse mylyn config require:: uername/password

i thing i can do is to change Gerrit server login type to LDAP.
Thanks.

if you any more suggestion please share..

Comment: Changed my Gerrit login type to HTTP. I can now user my username & generate my password from profile Setting section.