# How to use ASP.NET Core Identity without IdentityServer4?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

We are starting a new web application that will be hosted in our customers infrastructure. Since this is a solution that will be here for a while and serve as a base for a lot of future products, we wanted to have a future proof security, that would be future poff (SSO / MFA) but this is something for like in 3 years. It's important for our customer that we rely on some standards, so I thought about using OpenId.

The solution will be based on ASP.NET Core + Angular. So I found out there was ASP.NET Core Identity, already compatible with OpenID Connect, but then I saw [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-6.0) that Microsoft recommends Duende Identity Server (IdentityServer4).

The problem is that we are a small team, building a small application, but in a big enterprise, so will have to go for the licensed version. The other problem is that since its our customers that deploy themself the application, we do not control how many servers will be deployed, therefore we would have to opt for an "enterprise" subscription, which is totally out of our budget.

Despite this, we were hoping that we could still use ASP.NET Core Identity to connect to different sources of users, manage permissions for our app, use the attributes on our controllers.

So, how to use ASP.NET Core Identity, without using IdentityServer?

Comment: Use PHP instead . However I think OpenIddict is still open-source with the Apache license, so a viable option

Comment: Would using local accounts be an option? This way you store the user data in your own database

Comment: Accounts local to what? The solution will be deployed inside of docker components, and we have to be able to backup them. So if you're talking about a local database, yes, how?

Comment: By the way, most enterprises do not use anything related to IdentityServer, but opt for [Azure ActiveDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/add-application-portal-setup-sso) instead. As far as I understand, it's way more flexible to configure

Comment: @Pieterjan I wish I could, but most of our clients are running this on their private network without internet access, I'm not sure how Azure Active Directory would work then? This is used to monitor critical infrastructure(power plant).

Comment: can i ask  you , what solution did you choose ?

Comment: @CSharp-n Currently none, but we will probably go for the Duende option when required

Answer (score 3):

According to the MSFT [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio)

> ASP.NET Core Identity adds user interface (UI) login functionality to
> ASP.NET Core web apps.
> To secure web APIs and SPAs, use one of the
> following:
>
> - Azure Active Directory Azure
> - Active Directory B2C (Azure AD B2C)
> - IdentityServer4

So they first offer their cloud solutions.
Identityserver4 [free version](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4) is still supported though till the .Net Core 3.1 EOL.
As a free-free option without any predefined EOL, you can try this [OpenIddict](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-samples/blob/dev/samples/Velusia/Velusia.Server/Startup.cs) sample as a start point for your solution, however it has a bit more gaps to be filled in yourself.
And [here](https://kevinchalet.com/2021/05/24/asp-net-core-6-and-authentication-servers-the-real-bait-and-switch-is-not-the-one-you-think/) is an explanation why MSFT don't offer it in their docs (spoiler: see above)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is a solution for critical infrastructure monitoring, so as of today, most of our customer doesn't want to have those network connected to internet. I will read about OpenIddict. Do you have anything in mind when you speak about "gap to be filled" ?

Comment: possibly I was not exact. the "gaps" i mentioned were not lack of common features, but a general requirement to set up everything manually (starting from the protocol endpoints), while Idenityserver provides most of the implementations together with common settings out of the box, requiring you to override only the places you really need to customize

Answer (score 2):

You can use pure ASP.NET Core without `IdentityServer`.
It's quite easy if you're using the same backend for authentication and API.

Example (copied from [source](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3669188/how-to-implement-jwt-authentication-in-aspnet-core-6.html)):

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text;
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(o =>
{
    o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
        ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey
            (Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"])),
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = false,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true
    };
});
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
var app = builder.Build();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.MapGet("/security/getMessage", () => "Hello World!").RequireAuthorization();
app.MapPost("/security/createToken",
[AllowAnonymous] (User user) =>
{
    if (user.UserName == "joydip" && user.Password == "joydip123")
    {
        var issuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"];
        var audience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"];
        var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes
        (builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"]);
        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
            {
                new Claim("Id", Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.UserName),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email, user.UserName),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti,
                Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
             }),
            Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5),
            Issuer = issuer,
            Audience = audience,
            SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials
            (new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
            SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512Signature)
        };
        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
        var jwtToken = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
        var stringToken = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
        return Results.Ok(stringToken);
    }
    return Results.Unauthorized();
});
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.Run();
```

See also:

- [Similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54739794/pure-asp-net-core-identity-server)

Answer (score 0):

According to their website it is free to use if your company's revenue is less than $1 million - [Link](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

Also see the screenshot:

[image]

Regarding Identity & IdentityServer. You can definitely use ASP.NET Core Identity without IdentityServer. IdentityServer adds OAuth 2.0, OpenID connect etc. Their is an excellent [doc on Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/how-to-choose-identity-solution?view=aspnetcore-8.0) which explains how to choose between basic ASP.NET Core Identity or OIDC servers.

You can also use IdentityServer4 which is the previous version of it, [see this](https://www.yogihosting.com/identityserver-aspnet-core-identity-mongodb-database/). It's licence is even more friendly than Newer Duende version.