# Use case of openID

Tags: authentication, oauth, openid

I am a bit confused about the use case of openID.

say, if a user login to a web application using openID. Should this web application create an account for the user?

1). if it should, then what is the difference between using openID and using OAuth (set scope to "profile") to get the information of the user and then create an account for the user. (later login can use unique key from profile/id token to find the user in database)

2). if it shouldn't, then if the user logout, and then login using openID again, all the activity the user previously did (for instance, saved some article for later reading) has gone (assume no cookie/session is set, since they are limited to one device). if so, what is the point of authentication under this scenario

I understand openID is an extension of OAuth, specifically designed for authentication, but when and how should I use openID for authentication?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

As EmCode pointed out OAuth is meant for authorization, OpenID Connect is meant for authentication. This means that using an OAuth flow, eventually you get an access token which let's you access a user's resources (or perform actions as that user). When using an OIDC flow you get an ID token which tells you who the user is. Of course you can mix both and get an ID token and an access token as a result of an OIDC flow.

For example:

You have an app which uses Google as the IdP for an OIDC login flow. When the user clicks the login button, they confirm identity at Google, and your app gets back an ID token. This token **does not** allow your app to access any of the user's resources controlled by Google (mail, calendar, photos, etc.). It just gives you information who the user is - maybe their name, email address, age, etc. based on what you requested with scopes.

If you used an OAuth flow, and asked the user to allow your app to access their calendar, then you would get an access token from Google. With this token you could call the Google calendar API to get the user's events, etc.

Once you have an ID token from an IdP, what you would usually do is to create an account in your app and connect it with the identity you got from the IdP. This allows you to save any relevant state/business data about your user. What OIDC gives you is that the user doesn't have to enter any passwords when logging in to your site - they can log in using Google, and your app will still know who the user is.

Comment: Hm but an ID token alone is not enough to sign in to the app, right? It is the access token containing the audience and scope, does this not have to be validated to ensure that the user is allowed to login to your app?

Comment: An ID token is enough to sign in to the app. If you trust the issuer of the ID token then you get a confirmation of who the user is. Signing in means authenticating, and once authenticated, you can assign the user some permissions (scopes). The decision whether you want to allow the user to log in to your app is yours alone. No data that you get from, e.g. Google's ID token will tell you this. Once you have that token, you can refer to your data about the user and make decisions about whether you want to log her in or not.

Comment: Imagine two applications that use ADFS as OpenID Provider. ADFS permits login for everyone for App 1, while limiting access to a certain AD group for App 2 where the user is not a member of. If only the ID token is validated, wouldn't the user be able to get an ID token by accessing App 1, then passing the ID token to App 2?

Comment: App2 is responsible for validating the ID token. It should check whether the token is for an expected audience (which should be app2). Additionally, it should use a nonce parameter to ensure that the ID token is not injected (in an OIDC flow the app sends a nonce parameter to the server. The server then puts it in the ID token. The app can then verify that the value of the nonce from the ID token matches the one it has locally). So, you can make all that verification using just the ID tokens.

Answer (score 0):

OpenID is indeed an OAuth extension but it might be confusing,

**OAuth2.0** : Authorization

**OpenID Connect** : Authentication

if you do all the authentication on your side, use OpenID Connect, if you only need to authorize you can use OAuth2.0 (if you have an already existing way of authenticating like SAML 2.0).

OpenID Connect add the JWT token that is standard for authentication (ID token). Remember that they are both standards, so you should follow it by reading the corresponding documentations.

You could use OAuth2.0 alone to do the authentication but it's not supposed to be like that and you would probably be out of the standard.

Similar question see : [What's the difference between OpenID and OAuth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087031/whats-the-difference-between-openid-and-oauth)