# Open ID Connect Flow and OAuth Grant

Tags: oauth, openid-connect, difference

I can't understand difference between OAuth authorization_code `grant` and OIDC authorization_code `flow`. For me it seems that this grant and flow are the same. If that's true, why use OIDC? If not, then when to use OIDC and OAuth? I have read a lot of blogs and questions on various forums, but I still can't understand it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between OpenID and OAuth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087031/whats-the-difference-between-openid-and-oauth)

Comment: Ok, now I'm feel more confused. I don't know if I understand it correctly, but when using client_credentials I am using OAuth and when using authorization_code I am using Open Id Connect? So why does the OAuth protocol in the documentation contain a authorization_code grant?

Comment: OIDC is a supetset of OAuth2. All OIDC are also OAuth2 flows; not all OAuth2 flows involve OIDC. You don't pick one or the other; if you're using OIDC, you're also using OAuth2 at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, the terminology between [OAuth](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics-13#section-3.1.1) and [OpenID Connect](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-basic-1_0.html#CodeFlow) are sometimes confusing.

The flow is the same, OpenID Connect is only an extra layer on top of OAuth.

When you use OAuth, you receive an `access_token`, which grants you access to a resource server. **The `access_token` proves authorization.** So the resource server has no idea who you are, only that you may access resources.

When you use OpenID Connect, and provide the `openid` scope when requesting the authorization code, you receive an extra token, the `id_token`.

This `id_token` is [a signed JWT token](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-basic-1_0.html#StandardClaims) which holds the identity of the user. Optionally you can add more scopes for [more claims](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-basic-1_0.html#StandardClaims) in your `id_token`. **The `id_token` proves authentication.**

Also, if you support OpenID Connect, but the client does not provide the `openid` scope, you don't receive an `id_token` but only the OAuth tokens.

So the flows are identical, only difference is the `id_token`.