# WSO2 Api Manager Keycloak Claims

Tags: keycloak, wso2-api-manager

I've successfully configured Keycloak as identity server for WSO2 api manager and I need am able to login to keycloak and, with the bearer, call a WSO2 defined rest API.
Now I need to make WSO2 send to the backend, also claims based on keycloak user's information, like role, group or property.
WSO2 apim 4.1.0 and Keycloak 19

Comment: Can you update the question with which API Manager version you are using? Also, can you edit the question with more elaboration? Do you want to pass the Keycloak information to the actual Backend Endpoint? Or is it you want to use the Keycloak Access token to invoke the API?

Answer (score 0):

You can't group information from access token's claims but you can get  client role, realm role, user name, username and client name.

User group or group member can get by separate API call.

You need to start this order
create realm -> create client -> add realm role -> add client role -> add user (with credential) -> assign realm role to user -> assign client role to user

Then
get access toke for user with grant_type is "password"

[image]

decode access token by [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/)
[image]

Finally can map between Keycloak settings and token's claims
[image]

You needs to understand how to access the resource by Role Based Access Control in Keycloak.
Here is [good explain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42186537/resources-scopes-permissions-and-policies-in-keycloak) for **Resources, scopes, permissions and policies in keycloak**

Comment: Can I made the role to pass to wso2 and arrive to the api in the claims?

Comment: WSO2 is back-end, it can get access - token from front-end. It means a role can pass from IdP to WSO2 via front-end.  But WSO2 needs to decode an access token. example [here](https://www.programcreek.com/python/?CodeExample=get+claims)

Comment: But maybe it can receive from keycloak infos about the user, no?

Comment: WSO2 got access token from front- end, you can do both ways #1 decode it with not extra API call or #2 ask to Keycloak what is user informaton.

Comment: This is how to get user informaton to ask toKeycloak [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73118975/oauth-to-oidc-keycloak/73126707#73126707)

Comment: Yes I know, but this is "handmade" and not generic (if I need to change the SSO server for example), instead I need that WSO2 get the infos from Keycloak ad use it as claims for the backend. I know that I can do it with a custom addon on WSO2, I can do it, but I wondered if there was already a ready and standard mechanism

Comment: Yes, [Keycloak REST API](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/18.0/rest-api/) can do it.

Comment: This is not generic and couple the rest service to keycloak...the claims are more generic

Comment: I don't know generic mean.

Comment: Right, I'll give you an example: now I have Keycloak as SSO for example and all my rest api are behind wso2, they read the claims and do things using the claims, tomorrow I'm going to change my SSO but I want the rest application still use the claims. In your solution I need to change the interaction with keycloak with an interaction with other sso sw