# kubeconfig - oidc based authentication

Tags: kubernetes, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, kubectl

Below is my kubeconfig file for accessing kubernetes clusters:

```
kind: ClientConfig
apiVersion: authentication.gke.io/v2alpha1
spec:
  name: dev-corp
  server: https://10.x.x.x:443
  certificateAuthorityData: ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc
  authentication:
  - name: oidc
    oidc:
      clientID: aaaaad3-9aa1-33c8-dd0-ddddd6b5bf5
      clientSecret: ccccccccccccccccc-
      issuerURI: https://login.microsoftonline.com/aaaa92-aab7-bbfa-cccf-ddaaaaaaaa/v2.0
      kubectlRedirectURI: http://localhost:12345/callback
      cloudConsoleRedirectURI: http://console.cloud.google.com/kubernetes/oidc
      scopes: offline_access,profile
      userClaim: upn
      userPrefix: '-'
      groupsClaim: groups
  preferredAuthentication: oidc
```

---

There are different OAuth grant types.

My understanding is, above OAuth grant type is *client credential* grant type, that requires client_id, client_secret, token URL(`issuerURI`), scope

---

1. What is the significance of fields `kubectlRedirectURI`, `cloudConsoleRedirectURI`, `userClaim`, `userPrefix`?
2. How OIDC different from OAuth2?
3. `oauth2.Config` does not store `userClaim` & `userPrefix`, `groupsClaim` information
   , as shown here.... https://github.com/golang/oauth2/blob/master/oauth2.go#L41

   How to store `kind:ClientConfig` with oidc based authentication into cache? for example `api.Config` can be  stored with an API from [client-go](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go) to write `api.Config` as shown [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/issues/711#issuecomment-741650574).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**KUBECTL_REDIRECT_URL**: the *redirect URL* that kubectl oidc login uses for authorization. This is typically of the format `http://localhost:PORT/callback`, where `PORT` is any port above `1024` that will be available on developer workstations, for example `http://localhost:10000/callback`. You must register the URL with your OIDC provider as an **authorized redirect URL** for the client application.

**USER_PREFIX**: prefix prepended to user claims to **prevent conflicts** with existing names. By default, an issuer prefix is appended to the userID given to the Kubernetes API server **(unless the user claim is email)**. The resulting user identifier is ISSUER_URI#USER. We recommend using a prefix, but you can disable the prefix by setting `USER_PREFIX to -`.

**userClaim**: the `user identifier` in the token under the claim name configured in `spec.authentication.oidc.userClaim` in the client configuration file.

**cloudConsoleRedirectURI** the name tell the story, the cloud redirect URL for OIDC, for example in case of google `https://console.cloud.google.com/kubernetes/oidc`

OIDC vs OAuth2

[What's the difference between OpenID and OAuth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087031/whats-the-difference-between-openid-and-oauth)

The file in the question from OIDC and you are comparing the value with Oauth, both handling at different way, better to update the question again with Oauth config file.

[api-server-authentication](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/api-server-authentication)

you can check [kubeconfig builder](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/kops/pkg/kubeconfig)

[kubernetes-engine-oidc](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/oidc)

> How to store kind:ClientConfig with oidc based authentication into cache?

you can write to a file and then read, or somewhere in the cloud storage as well

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73382594/how-to-write-kindclientconfig-to-kube-config