# OIDC connect using kubernetes API to talk to kubernetes cluster

Tags: go, gcloud, kubectl, google-authentication, google-anthos

`kind:ClientConfig` stored in `.kube/config` yaml, looks like:

```
kind: ClientConfig
apiVersion: authentication.gke.io/v2alpha1
spec:
  name: dev-corp
  server: https://10.x.x.x:443
  certificateAuthorityData: ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc
  authentication:
  - name: oidc
    oidc:
      clientID: aaaaad3-9aa1-33c8-dd0-ddddd6b5bf5
      clientSecret: ccccccccccccccccc-
      issuerURI: https://login.microsoftonline.com/aaaa92-aab7-bbfa-cccf-ddaaaaaaaa/v2.0
      kubectlRedirectURI: http://localhost:12345/callback
      cloudConsoleRedirectURI: http://console.cloud.google.com/kubernetes/oidc
      scopes: offline_access,profile
      userClaim: upn
      userPrefix: '-'
      groupsClaim: groups
  preferredAuthentication: oidc
```

---

With kubectl, above config is used as:

```
 $ gcloud components install kubectl
 All components are up to date.
 $
 $ kubectl oidc login --login-config ~/.kube/config --cluster dev-crop
```

to authenticate and then talk to cluster(as shown below):

```
 kubectl get ns
```

---

`kubectl` is also GoLang based tool, which is able to load config from `--login-config` and then authenticate.

```
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"22+", GitVersion:"v1.22.12-dispatcher-dirty", GitCommit:"fde00375407ad0afadd681a3505054ec83f935ec", GitTreeState:"dirty", BuildDate:"2022-07-19T19:06:19Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.15", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"windows/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21", GitVersion:"v1.21.5-gke.1200", GitCommit:"90a16981ade07f163a0233adb631b42ac1fc53ff", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-10-04T09:25:23Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.7b7", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

---

In our scenario, above configuration is actually stored in database(mongodb collection):

```
  [
    {
      "apiVersion": "authentication.gke.io/v2alpha1",
      "name": "dev-corp"
      "server": "https://10.x.x.23:443"
      "certificateAuthorityData": "ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc"
      "clientID": "aaaaad3-9aa1-33c8-dd0-ddddd6b5bf5"
      "clientSecret": "ccccccccccccccccc-"
      "issuerURI": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/aaaa92-aab7-bbfa-cccf-ddaaaaaaaa/v2.0"
      "kubectlRedirectURI": "http://localhost:12345/callback"
      "cloudConsoleRedirectURI": "http://console.cloud.google.com/kubernetes/oidc"
      "scopes": "offline_access,profile"
      "userClaim": "upn"
      "userPrefix": "-"
      "groupsClaim": "groups"
      "preferredAuthentication": "oidc"      
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "authentication.gke.io/v2alpha1",
      "name": "test-corp"
      "server": "https://10.x.x.24:443"
      "certificateAuthorityData": "dddddddddddddddddddddddddfeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeccccccccccccccc"
      "clientID": "bbbbb3-9aa1-33c8-dd0-ddddd6b5bf5"
      "clientSecret": "eeeeecccccccccc-"
      "issuerURI": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/aaaa92-aab7-bbfa-cccf-ddaaaaaaaa/v2.0"
      "kubectlRedirectURI": "http://localhost:12345/callback"
      "cloudConsoleRedirectURI": "http://console.cloud.google.com/kubernetes/oidc"
      "scopes": "offline_access,profile"
      "userClaim": "upn"
      "userPrefix": "-"
      "groupsClaim": "groups"
      "preferredAuthentication": "oidc"      
    }
  ]
```

---

After loading above data(from mongodb) into a cache(user defined struct shown below):

```
type ClientConfig struct {
    // ClientID is the application's ID.
    ClientID string

    // ClientSecret is the application's secret.
    ClientSecret string

    // Endpoint contains the resource server's token endpoint
    // URLs. These are constants specific to each server and are
    // often available via site-specific packages, such as
    // google.Endpoint or github.Endpoint.
    Endpoint Endpoint

    // RedirectURL is the URL to redirect users going through
    // the OAuth flow, after the resource owner's URLs.
    RedirectURL string

    // Scope specifies optional requested permissions.
    Scopes []string

    ApiVersion string
    ServerName     string              // "dev-corp" in above case
    ServerURL string                   // "https://10.x.x.24:443"
    CertificateAuthorityData string 
    CloudConsoleRedirectURI string
    UserClaim  string
    UserPrefix string
    GroupsClaim string
    PreferredAuthentication string      
}
```

---

`kubectl` is able to load this config with `--login-config` option

How to load config from
cache and authenticate with kubernetes cluster(in google cloud)? Goal is to  manage the cluster using kubernetes API. [oidc-auth-plugin](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/master/plugin/pkg/client/auth/oidc/oidc.go) has no support to load this config.