# How do I get the referrer URL in an ASP.NET MVC action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, referrer

How do I get the referrer URL in an ASP.NET MVC action? I am trying to redirect back to the page before you called an action.

Comment: Bear in mind that not all user-agents (AKA browsers) will send the referrer information, and some may even fake it.

Answer (score 155, accepted):

You can use `Request.UrlReferrer` to get the referring URL as well if you don't like accessing the `Request.ServerVariables` dictionary directly.

Comment: It is exactly what I need. Thank you, bro!

Comment: `Request.UrlReferrer` is actually the URI but from there you can get everything you need regarding the referrer URL.  (More about URI vs URL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176264/what-is-the-difference-between-a-uri-a-url-and-a-urn).

Answer (score 20):

```
Request.ServerVariables["http_referer"]
```

Should do.

Answer (score 9):

You can use this

```
filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath
```

Comment: This would work in a filter context, but not in the action context as the question asked for.

Answer (score 4):

You can pass referrer url to viewModel, in my opinion it's better approach than sharing via the state, try so:

```
public interface IReferrer
{
    String Referrer { get; set; }
}
```

...

```
public static MvcHtmlString HiddenForReferrer<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper) where TModel : IReferrer
{
    var str = htmlHelper.HiddenFor(hh => hh.Referrer);
    var referrer = HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri;
    return new MvcHtmlString(str.ToHtmlString().Replace("value=\"\"", String.Format("value=\"{0}\"", referrer)));
}
```

...

```
@Html.HiddenForReferrer()
```

Comment: huh, never realized underscore by itself is a valid variable name. How 'bout that.

Comment: @BVernon The real question is why anyone would use it that way.  The only convention I am aware of with a single underscore for a name is to signify that it's just a placeholder for a variable you don't want or need.

Comment: @Daniel I agree, fixed