# Getting the HTTP Referrer in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, http-headers, http-referer

I'm looking for a quick, easy and reliable way of getting the browser's **HTTP Referrer** in **ASP.Net** (**C#**).  I know the HTTP Referrer itself is unreliable, but I do want a reliable way of getting the referrer if it *is* present.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the referrer URL in an ASP.NET MVC action?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471188/how-do-i-get-the-referrer-url-in-an-asp-net-mvc-action)

Comment: Fro Asp.Net Core see [How can I get Url Referrer in ASP.NET Core MVC?](//stackoverflow.com/q/38772394)

Answer (score 185, accepted):

You could use the [UrlReferrer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx) property of the current request:

```
Request.UrlReferrer
```

This will read the [Referer](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.36) HTTP header from the request which may or may not be supplied by the client (user agent).

Comment: It should be noted that this property will throw a System.UriFormatException if the referer HTTP header is malformed.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov Am trying to create a REST API using WEB API. UrlReferrer is not part of the Request object. Should i add some "using" etc. What am I missing? a DLL?

Comment: It should be noted that the Difference is spellings is correct. The http header is misspelled. MS uses the correct spelling in the property name. Unfortunately, the two do not match, which can cause some people (me) confusion when testing.

Comment: Be careful if you are using `Request.UrlReferrer` after a server side postback.  Of course `Request.UrlReferrer` will now have the value of the page you are posting back to.  In most cases, people need the previous page.  In this case, ensure you are storing the previous page in say a viewstate variable when the page first loads.  And then when you access this variable it has the previous page you came from.  For example, in asp.net forms page load event you can do: `if (Request.UrlReferrer != null) 
                    ViewState["PreviousPageUrl"] = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();`

Comment: ...and when you post back for instance, you could do: `Response.Redirect(ViewState["PreviousPageUrl"] != null
                        ? ViewState["PreviousPageUrl"].ToString()
                        : "SomeOtherPage.aspx");`

Comment: Valid `HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer`?

Comment: @darin dimitrov  The following code for my asp.net site returns null, when I try to open site from link on another site

 `If Not IsPostBack Then

        Dim referrer As Uri = HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer
        If referrer Is Nothing Then Response.Write("Null") Else 
            Response.Write(referrer.ToString)
        end if 

 end if`
And it writes "Null" every time. whats wrong?     I have changed page from where link comes and now works PHP script header(location: mysiteurl') but it still writs "Null"

Comment: Yeah remember Referer (sic) is often passed empty in headers which returns null here, so you better null check this thing! Request.UrlReferrer?.AbsoluteUri

Answer (score 34):

```
Request.Headers["Referer"]
```

## Explanation

#### The [`Request.UrlReferrer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer?view=netframework-4.8) property will throw a `System.UriFormatException` if the referer HTTP header is malformed (which can happen since it is not usually under your control).

Therefore, the `Request.UrlReferrer` property is not 100% reliable - it may contain data that cannot be parsed into a `Uri` class. To ensure the value is always readable, use `Request.Headers["Referer"]` instead.

As for using `Request.ServerVariables` as others here have suggested, per MSDN:

**Request.ServerVariables Collection**

> The ServerVariables collection retrieves the values of predetermined environment variables and request header information.

**Request.Headers Property**

> Gets a collection of HTTP headers.

`Request.Headers` is a better choice than `Request.ServerVariables`, since `Request.ServerVariables` contains all of the environment variables as well as the headers, where `Request.Headers` is a much shorter list that only contains the headers.

So the most reliable solution is to use the `Request.Headers` collection to read the value directly. Do heed Microsoft's warnings about HTML encoding the value if you are going to display it on a form, though.

Comment: Note that the `Referer` header is spelled differently than the `HTTP_REFERRER` server variable.

Answer (score 22):

Use the `Request.UrlReferrer` property.

Underneath the scenes it is just checking the `ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER")` property.

Comment: So there wouldn't be any different if I used: HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"] ?

Comment: In theory there's no difference, in practice I can't say for sure since a quick look with reflector shows that `UrlReferrer` does a lot more than a simple call to `ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER")`

Comment: I can tell you that `ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"]` returns a *string*, whereas `Request.UrlReferrer` returns a *Uri*.

Answer (score 15):

I'm using .Net Core 2 mvc,
this one work for me ( to get the previews page) :

```
HttpContext.Request.Headers["Referer"];
```

Answer (score 14):

Like this: [HttpRequest.UrlReferrer Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx)

```
Uri myReferrer = Request.UrlReferrer;
string actual = myReferrer.ToString();
```

Comment: To safeguard against null, you can say: string actual = "" + Request.UrlReferrer ?? "(default)"; // (default) can be empty string

Answer (score 10):

Since Google takes you to this post when searching for `C# Web API Referrer` here's the deal: `Web API` uses a different type of `Request` from normal `MVC Request` called `HttpRequestMessage` which does not include `UrlReferrer`. Since a normal `Web API` request does not include this information, if you really need it, you must have your clients go out of their way to include it. Although you could make this be part of your `API Object`, a better way is to use `Headers`.

First, you can extend `HttpRequestMessage` to provide a `UrlReferrer()` method:

```
public static string UrlReferrer(this HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    return request.Headers.Referrer == null ? "unknown" : request.Headers.Referrer.AbsoluteUri;
}
```

Then your clients need to set the `Referrer Header` to their `API Request`:

```
// Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Referrer = new Uri(url);
```

And now the `Web API Request` includes the referrer data which you can access like this from your `Web API`:

```
Request.UrlReferrer();
```

Answer (score 4):

Using .NET Core or .NET 5 I would recommend this:

```
httpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Referer", out var refererHeader)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
string referrer = HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
```

Comment: This is for ApiController. That's what I needed though.

Answer (score 2):

Sometime you must to give all the link like this

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
```

(in option when "Current" not founded)

Answer (score 1):

Belonging to other reply, I have added condition clause for getting null.

```
string ComingUrl = "";
if (Request.UrlReferrer != null)
{
    ComingUrl = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
}
else
{
    ComingUrl = "Direct"; // Your code
}
```