# How to know if a web request is made from particular another known website's link button

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, iis, web

I have two website

1) Main website: it has a link Help & Training that redirects user to another Help website.

2) Help website has no authentication rules thus anybody can visit the website directly.

Now I have a requirement to allow second website to be visited from first website's link, all the other request should be redirect to another page.

Offcourse querystring/parameter validation is not acceptable as that can be visible and constant

Is it possible, any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx which is just an ASP.NET wrapper around the HTTP referrer header.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer

This, of course, can be spoofed so don't rely on it for creating something super secure.

Answer (score 2):

what if you add a get parameter to the link's url in the first site and checks for it in the second site. That's of course a very simple solution and could be cheated pretty fast.

Comment: I suggested the same, but they don't accept as if anybody know the parameter they can still access the second site.

Answer (score 0):

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4258249/381819):

You could use the [UrlReferrer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx) property of the request:

```
Request.UrlReferrer
```

This will read the [Referer](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.36) HTTP header from the request which may or may not be supplied by the client (user agent).

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use this block of code to identify from where the user came to your website

```
 If Not IsPostBack Then
            If Not Request.UrlReferrer.ToString() Is Nothing Then
                referrer = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString()
            End If
        End If
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want something that's not easily spoofable by average users...

site2 exposes a webservice which validates a "secret" parameter (could just be some long random string that only site1 and site2 know).  this service returns a unique "token" that is only good for a small period of time.  site1 appends this token to the querystring when directing the user to site2.  site2 validates that the token is legit and still valid.  once a token has been used, site2 no longer treats it as valid.