# How to find from where the Request came to ASP.NET Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, httprequest

I have an ASP.NET Application deployed to IIS, application will be called from another separate website(Java based application which is like a portal), Can I find the URL of the that website (Java based application )from where the request came to my asp.net application ?

The reason why I need that requested URL is that in my application I have a HOME button when clicked should redirect the USER to the website(Java based application) from where my asp.net application is called. I can't hard code the URL as the request will come from multiple places (as that java based website is in multiple servers with different or same domain names).

Comment: *If* its available it will be in the Referrer: [Getting the HTTP Referrer in ASP.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258217/getting-the-http-referrer-in-asp-net) Or use JavaScript; `window.history.go(-1)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most reliable way is probably to have the "home" application provide a "return URL" when it links to your application.  Something like:

```
<a href="http://yourserver/yourapplication?HomeURL=http%3A%2F%2Fhomeserver%2Fhomeapplication
```

Then in your application you'd check the query string for that value and probably just keep it in session or some transient session-like persistence:

```
Session["HomeURL"] = Request.QueryString["HomeURL"];
```

(Or of course something less coupled to the HTTP Context if possible, particularly in an MVC application.)

You can perhaps create a default of some sort of none is provided, maybe linking back just to your application's home or perhaps trying to get the value from `Request.UrlReferrer` (which isn't always available).  Then your "Home" link would be that value, at least for the duration of that user's session (or however long you persist it).

Comment: Request.Referrer is not available for me in al cases for me. appending ReturnURL will work for me.. thank You.!!