# Sending Traffic to Another website

Tags: php, asp.net-mvc, redirect

This must be a stupid question, but I was wondering. How do I know if a certain visitor who visit my site came from another site by clicking a redirected link going to my website?

it's like redirecting a traffic.

is it possible to track if that user came from a specific site by clicking a link there going to my site?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You mean like who was the referring website?

Comment: @etrey Yes, it's like referring..

Comment: Well, in most cases you can use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFER']` but it's not always accurate, other than that, if the site sends a parameter with the URL / HTTP then you can also use that (Although that requires that you know / have a deal with the other site).

Comment: Should be able to see the referrer via most analytics packages installed to your site. Google Analytics for example will provide the exact page. EDIT: I assumed you were asking for general knowledge, if this is specifically for PHP than I agree with @Epodax , HTTP Refer not generally reliable.

Comment: use a referring url like index.php?ref=1234. Then collect hit count

Comment: @Epodax I see... Yes, it must have a deal with both parties.. thanks this gives me an idea.

Comment: @etrey how about in asp.net? how can I do that? is there an equivalent code for `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFER']` in ASP.NET? or the only choice is google analytics?

Comment: @etrey Hence why I said "It's not always accurate," Although it should properly have been worded as not accurate :)

Comment: It's not necessarily that Google Analytics is the only option for this, but it is an option to track incoming traffic for general data gathering. Are you trying to program this into something, however? Or just want to keep general stats

Comment: @etrey I am going to program this.. to know if that user came from an affiliated site... I want to see in the userdetails where this user came from. is it from affiliated sites or direct visit.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258217/getting-the-http-referrer-in-asp-net You could use the UrlReferrer property of the current request:

`Request.UrlReferrer`