# Url Referrer is not available in WebApi 2 MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, controller, asp.net-web-api2, httpcontext

I have an MVC WebAPI 2 project with a `Controllers` controller. The Method I'm trying to call is `POST` (Create). I need to access the referring URL that called that method yet, no matter what object I access, the referring URL either doesn't exist in the object or is null.

For example, I've added the `HTTPContext` reference and the following returns `null`:

```
var thingythingthing = HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer;
```

The `Request` object does not have a `UrlReferrer` property.

This returns null as well:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"]
```

I cannot modify the headers because I need to be able to generate a link to the method and filter access by origin of the call.

Any particular place I should be look or, alternatively, any particular reason why those are returning null?

Edit: I have a solution for GET methods (`HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer`) but not for POST methods.

Answer (score 6):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32450093/1100441). Basically, WebAPI requests use a different kind of request object. You can create an extension method that provides a `UrlReferrer` for you, though. From the linked answer:

First, you can extend `HttpRequestMessage` to provide a `UrlReferrer()` method:

```
public static string UrlReferrer(this HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    return request.Headers.Referrer == null ? "unknown" : request.Headers.Referrer.AbsoluteUri;
}
```

Then your clients need to set the `Referrer Header` to their `API Request`:

```
// Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Referrer = new Uri(url);
```

And now the `Web API Request` includes the referrer data which you can access like this from your `Web API`:

```
Request.UrlReferrer();
```

Comment: The headers cannot be modified by the client in this case so I cannot use this for my purposes. I have a workaround that I could use but it would involve an intermediate page to redirect the call. I'm not keen on that. Also, see my question edit;

Comment: Ah. Carry on, then!