# Get request origin in C# api controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, cors, httpwebrequest, httprequest

Is there a way how can I can get request origin value in the api controller when I'm calling some api endpoint with ajax call?

For example I'm making this call from www.xyz.com:

```
$http({
    url: 'http://myazurewebsite.azurewebsites.net/api/ValueCall/CheckForExistingValuers',
    method: "GET",
    params: { loanID: $scope.loanIdPopup }
}).success(function (data) {

}).error(function (data) {

});
```

Once on the api side, how can I get the www.xyz.com value?

CORS is working properly.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258217/getting-the-http-referrer-in-asp-net

Comment: @Theo not a duplicate.

Comment: How not? You are looking for the referrer URL, no?

Comment: If you got CORS working, you should be able to fetch the Origin-header. Most modern browsers sent it.

Comment: I've added example how to take origin value form request, but I'm curious why do you need it if you have EnableCors attribute or web.config section or custom cors policies for configuration origin values

Answer (score 36, accepted):

What you're looking for is probably the origin-header. All modern browsers send it along if you're doing a cross domain request.

In an `ApiController` you fetch it like so:

```
if (Request.Headers.Contains("Origin"))
{
    var values = Request.Headers.GetValues("Origin");
    // Do stuff with the values... probably .FirstOrDefault()
}
```

Comment: I get this error: `"ExceptionMessage": "The given header was not found.",
  "ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",` I am using Postman.

Comment: Then the consumer probably does not send that header. But all modern browsers send it if it's cross domain.

Comment: Ahhhhh... The Url I am using is "http://localhost" just debugging in VS and running postman, maybe that's why?

Comment: That could be it. The browser adds the header when sending a request with ajax from one domain to another.

Comment: You are right, it worked from another solution but not in Postman. Awesome. Thank you! I already +1 your answer before your last answer ;)

Answer (score 13):

You can grab it from the API methods via current HTTP request headers collection:

```
  IEnumerable<string> originValues;
  Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Origin", out originValues)
```

Comment: Proper way to do this in .Net Core

Answer (score 8):

```
var originValue = Request.Headers["Origin"].FirstOrDefault();

// or

StringValues originValues;
Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Origin", out originValues);
```