# Which action redirected to the current action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Is it possible to check in an action, which action it was called by?

Sounds a little bit confusing but i try to explain in a short example

```
public IActionResult CallerAction1(){
    return Redirect("CalledAction")
}

public IActionResult CallerAction2(){
    return Redirect("CalledAction")
}

public IActionResult CalledAction(){
    // Who called me? Who redirected to me? 1 or 2?
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the HTTP Referrer in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258217/getting-the-http-referrer-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as in code, where you shouldn't care which method called the current method, you shouldn't care which action redirected to the current action.

If you take a step back and realise *why* you want to know this, you probably want to do something different based on the circumstances. In that case, you use parameters. And each caller passes a different parameter.

How to name this parameter, depends on what you want it to do. So, for example:

```
public IActionResult CalledAction(bool withFullDetails){
}

public IActionResult CallerAction1(){
    return RedirectToAction("CalledAction", new { withFullDetails = false });
}

public IActionResult CallerAction2(){
    return RedirectToAction("CalledAction", new { withFullDetails = true });
}
```

Comment: Thats suitable for my purpose, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No, not really. A redirect is a response in itself. It has a 301, 302 or 307 status code and a `Location` response header which contains the URL you are "redirecting" to. At that point it's done.

The client then *may* opt to send a new request for the URL that was in the `Location` header, and web browsers do by default. However, that's a brand new request, totally unrelated to the first that resulted in the redirect. HTTP is a stateless protocol, so each request is just as if it's the first the client has ever made with the server.

That said, there *may* be a `Referer` (sic) header attached to the request, and if so, this *may* contain the URL that was previously requested, but that's a client implementation detail, and not guaranteed or reliable (it can be spoofed).

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the action name or request path as query string and get it in `CalledAction`,for example

```
public IActionResult CallerAction1()
    {
        string actionName = this.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
        string requestPath = Request.Path.ToString();
        return RedirectToAction("CalledAction",new { path = requestPath, name = actionName });

    }

    public IActionResult CalledAction()
    {
        var fromPath = HttpContext.Request.Query["path"].ToString();
        var fromActionName= HttpContext.Request.Query["name"].ToString();

        // Who called me? Who redirected to me? 1 or 2?
        return View();
    }
```