# How to get the page URL if the page request is made from a different URL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I am working on a web application, I came to a situation that I need to know from which website the user came to my website.
What I am looking for is:

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://localhost:18835/index.aspx">To Web application</a>
```

is on one website say StackOverflow and on that `index.aspx` page load I need to know that the request is coming from StackOverflow or any other website I need to know the URL where the page request is made.

How can I do that?

```
string referencepage = HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri;
label1.Text = "You Came from:-" + referencepage;
```

this code will work when the request is made within the current URL, so what if the request is coming from outside ???

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting the HTTP Referrer in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258217/getting-the-http-referrer-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"] != null)
{
    Response.Write(Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"].ToString());
}
```