# I'm building an ASP.NET website using C#; I need to know which page the user came from

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

For example: user logged in and he is on a page called `userpage` and he clicks on the home button and is moved back to the home page.

How can I know that he's coming from the `userpage`?

Comment: Is this for ASP.NET Framework WebForms, or for ASP.NET Framework MVC, or for ASP.NET Core MVC, or for ASP.NET Core Razor Pages, or for ASP.NET Core Blazor? Best is to **[edit]** the question, please always be specific. Also, I wonder **why** you think you need to know this.

Comment: You could try `Request.UrlReferrer`. But it is not 100% reliably. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258217/getting-the-http-referrer-in-asp-net