# Redirecting back to the original url in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using ASP.NET MVC for creating a blog and whenever user post a comment the form is posted to the url /Post/AddComment but after successfully saving to database I want to redirect the user back to the post where they added comment for ex. http://myblog/archive/2010/11/post.aspx. How I can do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can probably get the URL referrer on the AddComment Action then redirect to that.

e.g.

```
public ActionResult AddComment(int blogId){
    var referer = Request.UrlReferrer;
    ViewBag.Referrer = referer;
    Return View();
}
```

Alternatively you could pass about a `ReturnUrl` in the query string an access this. So if you are clicking a button or a link on the blog post page to add a comment, you could add `returnurl=@Request.Url` This would then allow you to access this on the POST ActionResult.

```
// Get
public ActionResult AddComment(int blogId, string returnUrl){        
    Return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddComment(BlogComment blogComment, string returnUrl){
    // do your stuff then redirect to the return url.
}
```

Comment: I got a link here will help others http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471188/how-do-i-get-the-referrer-url-in-an-asp-net-mvc-action

Comment: That doesn't cover enough details.

Comment: @SepehrM added more details for you ;) This was an old answer when i didn't give a lot of detail