# Send URL referrer through contact form

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm going off this:
[How do I get the referrer URL in an ASP.NET MVC action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471188/how-do-i-get-the-referrer-url-in-an-asp-net-mvc-action)

It works. I am recieving a URL when my form is submitted, but it's the same URL the contact form is on.  I'm guessing when I hit submit, it thinks the previous page is the contact page. I'd like to find out the page the user was on BEFORE the contact form page.

This is what I have:

```
sb.Append("<p>Referrer URL: " + Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"] + "</p>");
```

Answer (score 2):

You could store the Referer in a hidden field in the form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="referer" value="<%=Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"] %>" />
```

Comment: it sent the actual string "<%=Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"] %>". Is that because I'm using Razor/C#?

Comment: @ChristopherNorthcutt To convert this to something like your original example, it would be: `sb.Append("<input type='hidden' name='referer' value='" + Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"] + "'/>");`

Comment: @JackA. I just want to send the text of the URL though not the entire input form. Right now I have this in the controller:

    sb.Append("<p>Referrer URL: " + Request["referer"] + "</p>");

and this in the .cshtml file:

    <input type='hidden' name='referer' value='" +  Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"] + "' />