# How to track incoming post URL in MVC controller

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I defined a HttpPost method in my asp.net MVC controller like below and my Post URL is http://mydomain/home/ebook

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ebooks(string email)
    {
        //insert email into Database
        return RedirectToAction("Incoming URL");
    }
```

And submitting my PHP form by declaring post action to my MVC controller’s HttpPost method in an another PHP website, my php website page URL is like http://myphpsitedomain/downloads.php

```
<form id="ebook" action="http://mydomain/home/ebook" method="post">        
<label for="email">Email</label>
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" required="required" />    
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

How to track PHP web page URL when PHP form (above)submitted to ASP.Net MVC HttpPost method?

Comment: [How do I get the referrer URL in an ASP.NET MVC action?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471188/how-do-i-get-the-referrer-url-in-an-asp-net-mvc-action)

Comment: `Request.UrlReferrer` is showing `null`

Comment: this appears to have nothing to do with PHP. It's a HTML form and a .NET MVC controller

Comment: You have php page with form and try to send this form to C# controller right?

Comment: It seems like `Request.UrlReferrer` is showing `null` in localhost but not at server.

Answer (score 0):

I'd post a comment but I don't have sufficient reputation. How is this even hitting the action method? Assuming you're following MVC conventions, an action named **ebooks** won't be reached from the form action **ebook**.