# Difference between URI and URL

Tags: url, terminology, uri

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between a URI and a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176264/whats-the-difference-between-a-uri-and-a-url)

If you read the documentation of CodeIgniter or Kohana, there is a lot of confusion about the usage of URI and URL. Sometimes they use one and other times the other. They also incorporate URI class which makes it easier working with URLs.

I know that:

- **URI** stands for **Uniform Resource Identifier**
- **URL** stands for **Uniform Resource Locator**

But that doesn't make much sense.  What exactly is the difference? or are they same?