# Where is the difference between locating and identifying a resource?

Tags: url, terminology, uri

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between a URI and a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176264/whats-the-difference-between-a-uri-and-a-url)

Is there any difference? I'm talking about URI for identifying, but URL for locating. Aren't both the same thing?

Comment: Duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984213/what-is-the-difference-between-uri-and-url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176264/whats-the-difference-between-a-uri-and-a-url

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They can look the same, but they're not the same thing. A URL identifies something that can be transferred over some protocol (often http). A URI, can be used to [identify a namespace (for example)](http://www.w3schools.com/XML/xml_namespaces.asp) but there might not be any content at the address.

Answer (score 2):

> Where is the difference between locating a ressource and identifying a ressource?

Knowing who I am doesn't tell you *anything* about where I am.

Answer (score 1):

A URI identifies a resource either by location, or a name, or both. More often than not, most of us use URIs that defines a location to a resource.

A URL is a specialization of URI that defines the network location of a specific resource.

Generally, if the URL describes both the location and name of a resource, the term to use is URI.

Answer (score 0):

This article might help:
[URI vs. URL](http://www.bernzilla.com/item.php?id=100)

Excerpt:

> "...a URL is a type of URI that
>   identifies a resource via a
>   representation of its primary access
>   mechanism (e.g., its network
>   "location"), rather than by some other
>   attributes it may have. Thus as we
>   noted, "http:" is a URI scheme. An
>   http URI is a URL. The phrase "URL
>   scheme" is now used infrequently,
>   usually to refer to some subclass of
>   URI schemes..."

Answer (score 0):

An identifier is a unique name for something, so we can be sure that we talk about the same thing. For example the Atom namespace is 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'. This is a URI. This doesnt mean that you can put this URI in a browser and have a document there (well, in case of Atom, yes, you have a document, but it's a simple presentation of Atom for convenience, it's not the Atom namespace itself).

A URL is the location of a document. This is what you can put in your browser. It is confusing that both use the same format (http://...) but that is mostly annecdotic ...

Answer (score 0):

A URL is a URI which is not a URN. ([see](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#URIs.2C_URLs_und_URNs))