# Difference between URL and URI?

Tags: url, uri

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between a URI and a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176264/whats-the-difference-between-a-uri-and-a-url)

Just to get it right:

URI = Tells you in which hotel you should go to sleep.

URL = Tells you in which room in what hotel you should go to sleep.

So URL is a lot more specific, it points to a final destination. The thing you want. While URI is something strange.

So what exactly is URI when it's not an URL? What's the real difference?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between URI and URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984213/difference-between-uri-and-url), [What's the difference between a URI and a URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176264/whats-the-difference-between-a-uri-and-a-url)

Comment: Hi! I've just created a video about this theme. Hope it helps to clarify: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RftwVvDKUAw&t=51s

Comment: Please see the question this duplicates.  It has attracted a MUCH better answer.  [What's the difference between a URI and a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176264/whats-the-difference-between-a-uri-and-a-url)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

URI: Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) is a string of characters used to identify a name or a resource on the Internet. Such identification enables interaction with representations of the resource over a network (typically the World Wide Web) using specific protocols

URL: In computing, a Uniform Resource Locator (URL) is a subset of the Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) that specifies where an identified resource is available and the mechanism for retrieving it.

**Example**

To identify a specific resource and how to access it - in all completeness

```
URI: mysql://localhost@databasename:password
```

The URL shows you where you can find the database on the internet and which protocol you should use.

```
URL: mysql://localhost
```

Comment: this is wrong. URL and URI are interchanged.

Comment: This is ambiguous and border-line incorrect. URLs are more specific than URIs. https://danielmiessler.com/study/url-uri/

Comment: While the cited definitions seem to be fine, the given example is misleading.

Comment: @RyanMcGeary The link is dead

Answer (score 20):

> "URI stands for Universal Resource
>   Identifier and URL stands for
>   Universal Resource Locator. Often
>   times people use the terms
>   interchangably, which is not entirely
>   correct. A URL is a subset of the URI
>   popular protocols. These are protocols
>   (http://, ftp://, mailto:). Therefore
>   all URLs are URIs. The term URL is
>   deprecated and the more correct term
>   URI is used in technical
>   documentation. All URIs are means to
>   access a resource on the Internet and
>   are a a technical short hand used to
>   link to the resource. URIs always
>   designate a method to access the
>   resource and designate the specific
>   resource to be accessed."- [Source](http://www.bernzilla.com/item.php?id=100)

Answer (score 2):

It's a [URN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Name), which identifies an item without giving any location.

Comment: Which one is the URN? I guess you're talking about the hotel example without pointing out the room? That's a URN?

Comment: That's one possible interpretation, yes.

Comment: Introducing a third term, in my opinion, is not the best way to help us understand the differences between the first two.