# Cannot set CSRF cookie using Laravel Sanctum on the frontend

Tags: javascript, laravel, axios, fetch-api, laravel-sanctum

I was recently trying to implement the Laravel Sanctum authentication with Nuxt 3, but have come across a problem with the initial CSRF cookie handshake. The thing is that after I make a request to the `http://localhost:8000/sanctum/csrf-cookie` path browser does not set the XSRF-TOKEN cookie. I am stuck on this problem for a week already and have not yet found a solution anywhere on the internet.
I tried using both Axios and Fetch API to set XSRF-TOKEN, yet with no success. I am using `http://localhost:8000` on the backend and `http://localhost:3000` on the front end. Laravel Sanctum itself works fine since I receive set-cookie headers when tested on Postman, but the browser does not receive them. I have set the following properties in the `.env` file:

```
    FRONTEND_URL=http://localhost:3000
    SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost:3000
    SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
```

I did everything to overcome the limitations of the CORS requests on front end. My fetch function looks as follows:

```
      window.fetch('http://localhost:8000/sanctum/csrf-cookie', {
        credentials: 'include',
      }).then((response) => {
        console.log(…response.headers)
      })
```

I have read that setting credentials to 'include' solves the problem, but even while doing so, I am unable to set XSRF-TOKEN. I tried to set credentials to 'same-origin', but that doesn't work either. Does anybody know how this problem could be solved?

Answer (score 2):

I understand your frustration with this, [@John Baker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11341689/john-baker). Most people seem scared of tutoring properly about the `CORS` issues faced when trying to get Nuxt 3 with Laravel as an API (Breeze + Sanctum API) to work properly. I'm having battles myself with it now and then, but referring back to my notes-to-self, as shared here, helps me out most of the time.

To try **"hitting the mark"** of your question about **"getting the csrf-cookie set"**. Here is a typical script snippet to **"set"** the csrf-cookie" in a typical login page. Note the `credentials: "include",` parameter used in both Methods. If not used you'll get a green `204` response, but the Application cookies would **not get "set"**:

#### login.vue

```js
<script lang="ts" setup>
  definePageMeta({
    // layout: "centered", // Use a layout-centered.vue file for this.
  });

  interface LoginPayload {
    email: string;
    password: string;
  }

  /* All of this will change later as you refactor these steps with custom Composables */
  const form = ref({
    email: "webmaster@abcd.com", // At this stage, Empty Values here will give you the 422 Status error.
    password: "SomEP@s$word",
  });
  
  async function handleLogin(payload: LoginPayload) {
    // Apply the LoginPayload
    await useFetch("http://localhost:8000/sanctum/csrf-cookie", {
      credentials: "include",
    });

    const token = useCookie("XSRF-TOKEN");

    await useFetch("http://localhost:8000/login", {
      credentials: "include",
      method: "POST",
      body: payload, // Apply the LoginPayload
      watch: false,
      headers: {
        "X-XSRF-TOKEN": token.value as string,
      },
    });
    console.log(payload); 
  }
</script>
```

However, stopping with just setting the application cookies would only create additional errors, so I'm including the rest of the **"CORS Onion layers"**.

As a starting point, it must be remembered what `CORS` is in comparison to `CSRF`. In short, `CORS` is a protection mechanism AGAINST `CSRF`. The "guard" against the "attacker". Referencing the Laravel Documentation on [CSRF Protection](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/csrf), and reading carefully through it will reveal that `CORS` is almost like an onion. It has different "layers" of protection that get applied via the `CORS` configuration files and entries of the Laravel API. `cors.php`, and the `.env` file are two files that are used as an **entry-point** to get the "guard" equipped with instructions on HOW the resource sharing should and shouldn't be implemented.

When we need to apply `CORS` to a SPA using Laravel as an API, we need to go a bit deeper and refer to the dedicated [SPA Authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/sanctum#spa-authentication) documentation and apply specific `CORS` "layers" for establishing protection against `CSRF`.

Currently, I can suggest two resources I came across, that are showing in detail the "Why" and "What", not just the typical "How". Without asking "Why, What, Where, When", then any "How" is useless. If people can't give you a reason why they are doing things and/or when and where to do them, it typically means they don't understand the topic very well. This is my opinion and based on experience, so don't take it as gospel.

**Now for the parts that you might find very helpful:**
Visit Constantin Druc's YouTube Channel. The man does a very decent job of explaining this extremely common frustration in two, fairly RECENT, tutorials (mid-2023).

1. Reference: [Laravel SPA Authentication - setup and common mistakes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2zKoS8GsKK8)

As partly mentioned by [Dipo Ahmed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11229002/dipo-ahmed), the key thing about basic `CORS` we need to keep in mind, is that **all three parts** of an URL MUST be identical.

The domain host/name `localhost` is NOT equal to the IP address  `127.0.0.1`. They get interpreted differently. If I'm correct, HTTP started off with IP addresses only, but soon it became clear that people would struggle to remember which IP address to use to be able to land on the desired website, so DNS was developed. It's like a "cross-referencing index" where the DNS knows both the IP address and the corresponding Domain Host or Name, which humans can relate to and the IP to which routing & networking devices and servers can relate to.

- The `URL Scheme` or `Protocol` whether it be `http://` or `https://`, or `www.`, or `https://www.`
- The `URL Domain Host (Name)` eg. `somedomain.com` or an IP Address `123.456.001`
- The `URL PORT` Number i.e. `8000`, `3000`, or `8080`

All three URL elements have to be exactly the same for `same-origin` resource sharing to occur seamlessly. This is easy to achieve in a situation where you might only use Laravel, acting as both the Front and Backend of your application. One Scheme, one Domain Host, and one PORT (assuming we use SQLite as a DB and not an external DB server, for example).

Although in this particular case, the question is about not being able to "set `CSRF` cookies", and `CORS` is directly involved, meaning we need to configure this "guard" to monitor the sharing of data between different URLs and **do so securely**. No valid ID-card = No entry. Enter `csrf-cookies`. But, it's not only the `csrf-cookies` that are needed. The instructions or headers in the cookie need to be clear and explicitly instruct the `CORS` guard about What, Who, When, then How, and How long to do its "duties". That is the `session` information given through. So, look at the API's `kernel.php` file's `The application's route middleware groups.` and the `sanctum.php` file's `return []` array. Then cross-reference it with the built-in Nuxt and custom `composables` used in the SPA's `layout`, `pages`, and `components` files.

Most probably, additional **`XSRF-TOKEN` cookies** and **`X-XSRF-TOKEN` headers** are needed. Think of it as a "deeper layer" of the onion mentioned earlier.

**Note:** `CSRF` does not function the same way for a typical `GET` request vs a `POST` request. Posting data from the SPA domain to the API domain is normally relatively easy. Getting the same information ( i.e. login credentials) back from the DB domain via the API domain to "check" a login attempt, is normally the culprit causing frustration.

**Additionally**, things may become more confusing in reference to `CSRF` protection, when you are also using `X-CSRF-Token`s and/or `X-XSRF-Token`s as applied to `URLs` and `URIs`. Refer to [CSRF Protection](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/csrf) in Laravel's documentation about protecting `URLs` and `URNs`. It's NOT the same as SPA `CSRF` Protection.

Both `URI` elements: `URLs` and `URNs` are used in a typical API-SPA scenario, and both are protected by `CORS` in a Laravel App or API. A suitable reference found [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4239941/difference-between-url-and-uri#4239952), which could be applicable to this particular question as well, discusses the difference in reasonable detail. Also see [RFC 3986 1.1.2, of Berners-Lee et al.](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-1.1.2).

These different CSRF Protection tokens look very alike, and I have wasted hours to try and figure out why my routes simply will not go through, meanwhile, it was the use of an incorrect TOKEN name that is hard to truly "see" even if it slaps you in the face. Look again:

[`X-CSRF-TOKEN` + `X-XSRF-TOKEN`]  vs  [`XSRF-TOKEN` + `X-XSRF-TOKEN`]

To summarise the core factors of applying `CORS` to obtain effective `CSRF` protection, the Laravel documentation should be read carefully and in context to gain full insight into the "Why" and "Where/When" first, before moving on to "How". It is imperative to know why you need it and where you want it in YOUR application and then move on to implementing its "layers" to suit the particular requirements of YOUR scenario. It's not a one-shoe-fits-all in every case.

2. Reference: [Laravel & Nuxt 3 Authentication Guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NY9yoqoN72w)

The second tutorial I recommend watching is focused on setting-up practical and suitable authentication routes between the SPA and API, using Nuxt **composables**, **interfaces** and **middleware**. (**Axios is NOT involved in the example**. Going the Axios path is a bit different, as you would need to install and configure Axios, and also create an `axiosPlugin.ts` file).

**Note:** Following Druc's tutorial, you might need to adjust your SPA's `login.vue`,`register.vue`, etc. files a bit when it comes to applying the `useFetch()` Composable vs. the `$fetch()` library, depending on your particular use-case. There are also differences between using Vue's `Options` vs. `Composition API`, so apply the relevant methods to suit your situation.

Both the tutorials focus on: A) understanding exactly What to do, Why you need to do it and then How `CORS` works in **general** as well as more specifically in the **Nuxt-Laravel-Sanctum context**, and B) how to use the `XCSRF` + `X-XCSRF` **Tokens** & **Headers** as mentioned in the [Laravel SPA Authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/sanctum#spa-authentication) documentation.

**Conclusion**
***Note:*** I am using `API` as the Root folder of the Laravel API, so remember to apply any folder names appropriate to your scenario. The same applies to the SPA.

A typical Nuxt-Laravel Dev Repo might look as follows:

```
**Main Project Directory**
   | [API] folder
   | [SPA] folder
   | .env
   | .git
   | <other default files>
```

You might be well aware, but I put it in here for people that might forget about "*small-mods-done-some-time-ago*" turning into frustration and thinking patterns that it's `CORS` causing all the crap again:)

**Keep the following in the back of your mind while working with the API:**

- Configure and refer to the `Cors.php` file when in doubt - stick to the defaults, unless you know exactly why you are changing paths in it.
- Configure and refer to the `RouteServiceProvider.php` file and apply the same strategy as for `Cors.php` above.
- Keep all the configuration files in `API/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/*.php` as they are, again only modify `guard` and `Redirect` Routes if you are familiar with **Why** you need to change them and **What** implications doing so has.
- The same goes for the `API\app\Http\Middleware` directory files and changes you may want to do there.
- The same goes for the files in the API's Root: `API/config/` and `API/routes/` folders.
- While working with the SPA, various sessions and Database exchanges will take place on the API. If some behaviour seems off, unexpected 422 responses or other strange behaviour is evident (password or user-name changes - they happen ), refer to the `API/storage/framework/sessions/` and `API/storage/framework/cache/data/` folders. The data and session files you will find in them sometimes contain invalid `session` or cached `data` information due to fundamental changes made in either the `API` or `SPA`.

> - They can safely be deleted while in developer mode, BUT delete [**the session files only**].
>
> > For example: Session files like `Au8etAwHyVuUK0o9wl1QSWSCJ9dfgYVCWRemAH7Q`
>
> - And also ONLY the [**sub-directories**] residing inside the `~/data/` directory.
>
> > For example: Sub-folders like `cc` or `c7`, etc.

- **DO NOT delete the `session` or `data` folders** themselves, nor the `.gitignore` or other files in them.

I hope it helps, and good luck!

Comment: any affiliation to that channel? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion)

Comment: No. There is no affiliation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that browser will not accept cookies from different ports.

Since you back-end is running on 8000 and front-end on 3000 The cookie that back-end provides will not be set on front-end.

So A workaround is to just disable the CSRF protection for API endpoints.
You can do this in your `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware.

add this line in you `$except` array and you will be good to go.

> '/api/*'

Comment: No you dont understand, this is the point of using Laravel Sanctum. It provides authentication benefiting from the Laravel web guard, which enables CSRF protection and session authentication. CSRF protection is a really crucial part of authentication, hence, it cannot be turned off for the route I am using.

Comment: Yes that would be true if you were building a monolithic application but in you case you back-end is just an API provider and there will be no session in between requests. So there is no need for CSRF protection but if you really need it you could take a look into proxy server which I don't have a good understanding of.

Comment: It is not only working as an API, but also authenticates users. In SSR applications there is still a need to use CSRF protection, which is precisely what Laravel Sanctum does. You can read more here: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sanctum#spa-authentication. I just need to figure out the way of receiving and actually setting CSRF token cookie.

Comment: But Why are you authenticating users with session? Since you front end is separate Authenticate the users like you would authenticate a mobile user with a bearer token. Then you won't need need any kind of session authentication

Comment: I am using Sanctum because its lightweight and robust, and certainly more modern approach.

Comment: Now I think I will still use Sanctum, but to authenticate with API tokens. I just thought having different ports is not a problem for session authentication.

Comment: @DipoAhmed you might need to checkout why session authentication is used with API.  Check this out, https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/sanctum#spa-authentication. With sanctum can either authenticate your API with token or session cookie, session cookie protects from cross site request forgery.