# How to load image file with space in name in android web view?

Tags: android

I have problem in loading image resource file in Android webview. Image name has space in words e.g,

```
file:///android_asset/images/abc xyz.jpg
```

So problem is webview consider %20 in name when ever space comes so it can not compare with  image which is inside asset folder.

I am not sure is there any problem with asset manager which is giving name like just abc I mean before space name or its problem in webview?.

Comment: try to read this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7986478/580131

Answer (score 0):

```
file:///android_asset/images/abc.html
```

create abc.html save this **abc.html** to your assets folder

```
...
<body>
<img src="file:///android_asset/images/abc xyz.jpg"/>
</body>
....

String url = "file:///android_asset/images/abc.html"
```

Comment: file name we can not change name should be as it is but we need to handle the space in name

Comment: read my answer carefully. you do not need to change image name. create one abc.html file and write above line in that file

Comment: I have tried what you suggest for put body tag but its not working