# What's the difference between path and URL in iOS?

Tags: ios, nsfilemanager

In a class such as NSFileManager there are 2 versions of practically every method.  One for paths and one for URLs.  What's the difference? And what's the best practice for converting a URL to a path.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

URL includes the protocol being used (http:// etc). Path doesn't or doesn't need at least.

Comment: Also, URLs can percent-encode characters like spaces. Paths don't do that.

Comment: I've also heard about URI (in addition to URL), what's the difference between URI/URL ?

Comment: URIs identify resources, URLs locate them:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913343/what-is-the-difference-between-uri-url-and-urn

Answer (score 30):

`path` is location of a resource (file/directory) in a `file system`. Just like iOS File System, other environments file system can be Windows file system, Unix etc. Path can have spaces like `/docs/random doc/`. (between random and doc)

`URL` is is a reference to a resource anywhere (file system, web HTTP, FTP etc). URL can not have spaces like path.

Web URL: `http://stackoverflow.com/`
file URL: `file://localhost/Users/username/docs/random%20docs/`
`path for above mentioned file URL`: `/Users/username/docs/random%20docs/`

in layman terms:

`URL` = protocol (http, file etc) + host (domain name or IP or localhost) + `path`

Comment: In iOS, you can call url.path to get path from a url.

Comment: `path` is an instance method and not a `property`. So better to use `[anyURLObject path]`.