# Need assistance regarding create directory methods on NSFileManager

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsfilemanager

[NSFileManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/createDirectoryAtURL%3awithIntermediateDirectories%3aattributes%3aerror%3a) has two methods to create directory, one ask for `path` and another ask for `url`. What `url` is for? Urls are for network but I don't see any network stuff in doc.

```
createDirectoryAtPath:withIntermediateDirectories:attributes:error:
createDirectoryAtURL:withIntermediateDirectories:attributes:error:
```

Comment: The same question is answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6546033/whats-the-difference-between-path-and-url-in-ios

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is contained at the same [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/createDirectoryAtURL%3awithIntermediateDirectories%3aattributes%3aerror%3a):

> The NSFileManager class supports both the NSURL and NSString classes
>   as ways to specify the location of a file or directory. **The use of the
>   NSURL class is generally preferred for specifying file-system items
>   because they can convert path information to a more efficient
>   representation internally.** You can also obtain a bookmark from an
>   NSURL object, which is similar to an alias and offers a more sure way
>   of locating the file or directory later.

Answer (score 2):

URLs come in 2 forms, network and [file](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURL/fileURLWithPath%3a). See:

```
NSURL *filePathURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:...];
```

A URL is just an organised definition of a path when you boil it down.

Comment: if using path to refer a file or directory what is the purpose of url?

Comment: URL is an alternative, you can use either

Answer (score 2):

To add to Visput and Wain's answers.

In your code you may be returning a file or directory path that is in the form of a NSURL from another method

An example would be the returned selection of a [NSOpenPanel](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/nsopenpanel_class/reference/reference.html).

It is alos easier to access the parts that make up the path in an  URL than it is in a string path

NSFileManager gives you the convenience method to use a NSURL that you already have from some where else.

Read up on [NSURL](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

> **Overview**
>
> An NSURL object represents a URL that can potentially contain the
>   location of a resource on a remote server, the path of a local file on
>   disk, or even an arbitrary piece of encoded data.
>
> You can use URL objects to construct URLs and access their parts. For
>   URLs that represent local files, you can also manipulate properties of
>   those files directly, such as changing the file’s last modification
>   date. Finally, you can pass URL objects to other APIs to retrieve the
>   contents of those URLs. For example, you can use the NSURLSession,
>   NSURLConnection, and NSURLDownload classes to access the contents of
>   remote resources, as described in URL Loading System Programming
>   Guide.
>
> URL objects are the preferred way to refer to local files. Most AppKit
>   objects that read data from or write data to a file have methods that
>   accept an NSURL object instead of a pathname as the file reference.
>   For example, you can get the contents of a local file URL as an
>   NSString object by calling the stringWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:
>   method, or as an NSData object by calling the
>   dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error: method.
>
> You can also use URLs for interapplication communication. In OS X, the
>   NSWorkspace class provides the openURL: method to open a location
>   specified by a URL. Similarly, in iOS, the UIApplication class
>   provides the openURL: method.
>
> Additionally, you can use URLs when working with pasteboards, as
>   described in NSURL Additions Reference (part of the AppKit framework).