# URI vs URL vs URN

Tags: java, url, uri, urn

Well there are lot of discussion, post, comments and questions over internet to differentiate URI, URL and URN.
One [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913343/what-is-the-difference-between-uri-url-and-urn/4913371#4913371%20explains%20the%20diffrence%20between) on SO explain about it, but i am confused in implementation result in my code.

**Q : If URI is super set of URL then how come it got this following output:**

```
URI : /XXX/abc.do 

URL : http://examplehost:8080/XXX/abc.do
```

When i write the below code:

```
System.out.println(“URI : “+ httpRequestObj.getRequestURI());
System.out.println(“URL : “+ httpRequestObj.getRequestURL());
```

**EDIT : Could you share a detailed answer by keeping JAVA and original concept of URI,URL and URN in scope.**

Regards,

Arun Kumar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If URI is super set of URL then how come it got this following output ...

The definitions of URI and URL cannot be used to infer the behaviour of [`getRequestURI()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURI%28%29) and [`getRequestURL()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURL%28%29).  To understand what the methods return, you need to read the javadocs and the Servlet specification.

The meaning of those methods are what they are because the `HttpRequest` API has evolved over time, and that evolution has had to maintain backwards compatibility.

`getRequestURI()` does return a URI, and `getRequestURL()` does return a URL, but the URI and URL are for different things.

Comment: Yes, as per JavaDoc, `getRequestURI()` Returns the part of this request's URL from the protocol name up to the query string in the first line of the HTTP request whereas `getRequestURL()` returns the string contains a protocol, server name, port number, and server path, but it does not include query string parameters.

Comment: Correct.  The explanation for what you observed is given by the javadocs ... not by any logical inferences from the definitions of URI, URL or URN.

Comment: *"Could you share a detailed answer by keeping JAVA and original concept of URI,URL and URN in scope."* - My answer already does that.

Comment: Yes but not completely. You are explaining that `getRequestURI()` and `getRequestURL()` in `HttpServerletRequest` are different from URI and URL concept.

Comment: @ArunKumar - Yes.  They are.  What *else* do you want to explain?

Comment: I want to know if If URI is super set of URL as per w3 definitions, how can i find it in JAVA?

Comment: i think Stephen is right here as per original question. I need to put another question for my above comment or someone can answer it here.

Answer (score 6):

java.net.URI API gives a good explanation:

*A URI is a uniform resource identifier while a URL is a uniform resource locator. Hence every URL is a URI, abstractly speaking, but not every URI is a URL. This is because there is another subcategory of URIs, uniform resource names (URNs), which name resources but do not specify how to locate them. The mailto, news, and isbn URIs shown above are examples of URNs.*

Comment: So does it mean `/XXX/abc.do` is a super-set of `http://examplehost:8080/XXX/abc.do` ??

Comment: @ArunKumar - No.  "/XXX/abc.do" is not a "set", so it cannot be a "super-set" of anything.

Comment: I am not sure what relations are between these two. URI API does not define super-set notion. According to API the first one is relative, the second is absolute. API also defines 3 operations between URI instances -  normalization, resolution, and relativization.

Comment: @EvgeniyDorofeev - In fact, this is not really about the `URL` and `URI` APIs.  The OP is confused about the meaning of the Strings returned by a couple of methods of the `HttpServletRequest` class.

Answer (score 0):

imagine you have a book. The URL (Uniform Resource Locator) is like telling someone the exact address of the library where the book is kept. It includes the specific location, like the street name and building number.

Now, URI (Uniform Resource Identifier) is a bit more general. It's like saying, "Look in the library on the science section shelf." It gives a general idea of where to find something but not the exact location.

Lastly, URN (Uniform Resource Name) is like a name tag on the book itself. It doesn't say where the book is in the library; it just gives it a unique name. So, URI is like telling where to find it roughly, and URN is like giving it a special name.

so in conclusion a URL might be also a URN and both are URIs

[image]