# What does a URI look like that is not a name?

Tags: rest, web, uri, terminology, rfc

[IETF RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-1.1.3) states that

```
A URI can be further classified as a locator, a name, or both.
```

I would be interested in an example of a URI that can not be considered being a name.

Comment: Possibly covered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913343/what-is-the-difference-between-uri-url-and-urn

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between a URI, a URL and a URN?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176264/what-is-the-difference-between-a-uri-a-url-and-a-urn)

Comment: I don't see my question answered in these supposed duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example is the [Content Identifier (RFC 2392)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2392) , eg. `cid:28432`, to reference resources like images inside the body of an email.
It's not a name and not globally scoped.