# Are mailto:'s valid URLs or valid URIs?

Tags: url, uri, mailto

Is `mailto:hola@correo.jp` a valid URL or a valid URI? Or both?

I need to choose a parsing library and I need to know this first in order to choose correctly.

Comment: Are you aware that these terms are often used synonymously?

Comment: @unor `often` means `not always`, in other words, they aren't technically synonymous. My question is about perfect technicalities, not slang that's "often" used.

Answer (score 2):

If you follow the contemporary view, the distinction between *URI* and *URL* is not useful. It’s recommended to use either *URI* or *URL* for everything. In practice, the terms are often used synonymously.

The two organizations mentioned below followed the recommendation to use only one term, but they didn’t use the same.

[Quotes and links in this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42546900/1591669)

#### IETF

It’s a ***URI***.

(According to [RFC 6068](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6068), which is currently IETF’s spec for the `mailto` URI scheme, via [Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) Schemes](https://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes/uri-schemes.xhtml).)

A previous RFC has called it ***URL*** ([RFC 2368](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2368)).

#### WHATWG

It’s a ***URL***.

(According to the [URL Living Standard](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/).)