# url scheme or url namespace, which is correct?

Tags: url, uri, vocabulary

I understand this question is quite pedant-prone but I like to have information sorted out the right way.
Anyway, after reading a post on Stackoverflow about difference between URL, URI and URN, I was directed to this paper: https://www.w3.org/TR/uri-clarification/

And it seems to me after reading that the wording **URI scheme** is correct, but **URL/URN/... scheme** is incorrect, that "http:", "isbn:" and the likes are really just **namespaces** and not **schemes**. But I googled a little and read **URL scheme** several times. I'm confused, since I'm not a native maybe I understand the document wrong.

Answer (score 0):

#### IETF

The IETF calls them ***URI schemes***.

Reference: [section 3.1 in IETF’s URI standard](https://tools.ietf.org/html/std66#section-3.1) (bold emphasis mine):

> The process for registration of new **URI schemes** is defined […]

(In the past, they also used other terms, e.g. *URL scheme names*.)

#### WHATWG

The WHATWG calls them ***URL schemes***.

Reference: [section 4.1. in WHATWG’s URL standard](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#url-representation) (bold emphasis mine):

> A **URL’s scheme** is an ASCII string that identifies the type of URL and […]

---

No surprises here, because the IETF recommends to use the term ***URI***, while the WHATWG recommends to use the term ***URL***. [Details in this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42546900/1591669)

The term *namespace* is, for example, used for certain parts of URNs (i.e., URLs/URIs with the `urn` scheme).

Comment: so in the end it all revolves around the confusion between uri and url? or since every url are uri, it's not wrong to talk about uri scheme in case of "url scheme"