# What is 'uniform' about URI, URL and URN [Uniform Resource Identifier, Uniform Resource Location, Uniform Resource Name]?

Tags: http, url, uri, urn

I have read about the differences of the URI, URN and URL [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176264/what-is-the-difference-between-a-uri-a-url-and-a-urn) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913343/what-is-the-difference-between-uri-url-and-urn) but the answers talk of the differences of the last letter, that is, the differences amongst identifier, name and location respectively.

What I have not understood is why all these terms have the word 'uniform' and what is uniform about them. This [Wikipedia section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Refinement_of_specifications) doesn't mention much about the reason why the change was made from 'universal' to 'uniform'.

I would like to find the missing explanation and not just memorize the terms as they are without fully understanding them.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Tim Berners-Lee’s own account, as published in his book *Weaving the Web*:

At an IETF meeting, Tim Berners-Lee tried to form a working group that would create an Internet standard for what he suggested to be named ***universal document identifiers***.

About the meeting, in his words (page 61):

> […] there was a strong reaction against the "arrogance" of calling something a universal document identifier. How could I be so presumptuous as to define my creation as "universal"? If I wanted the UDI addresses to be standardized, then the name "*uniform* document identifiers" would certainly suffice.

While he didn’t agree (it was an issue of whether the Web could be something "universal"), there wasn’t much time and so (page 62):

> I was willing to compromise so I could get to the technical details. So *universal* became uniform, and *document* became *resource*.

They formed "a uniform resource identifier working group". (And this group then decided that "identifier" wasn’t a good label, and they chose "locator" instead, forming "URL" – which he also didn’t agree with.)

---

The current [URI Internet standard](https://tools.ietf.org/html/std66) (RFC 3986) describes the meaning of "Uniform", "Resource" and "Identifier" in [section 1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-1.1).