# Azure Resource Identifier format URI -URL OR URN

Tags: azure, url, uri, urn

I am working with Azure and I have noticed that for every resource group and resource it created an ID that looks like this.

For Resource Groups
`/subscriptions/<Subscriptionid>/resourceGroups/<resourcegroupname>`

and For Resource it looks like this
`/subscriptions/<Subscriptionid>/resourceGroups/<resourcegroupname>/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/<disk name>`

This is azure's unique identifier.

What kind of URI is this, a URL or URN?

Comment: I don't think it is either: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4913371/1658906. That could be a path in a URL, but it doesn't contain a scheme nor a hostname.

Comment: Its is neither, [Azure Resource manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/overview#consistent-management-layer) terms it simply as `resource id`. URL scheme is abstracted away although it support REST SDK. You may simply consider it as hierarchical ID.

Answer (score 1):

well, it cant be urn, because its supposed to start with `urn`, so this is a url

[What is the difference between URI, URL and URN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913343/what-is-the-difference-between-uri-url-and-urn)

on the other hand, azure mentions these as resource ID everywhere, so probably not url, i think its just a URI thats somewhat unique to azure

Comment: But it does not have the protocol as part of the URI, so can it be a URL